# ¿Cómo funciona la estadística "porcentaje de preguntas contestadas" en Area 51?

Tags: soporte, estadísticas, preguntas-no-contestadas, fase-beta, area51

Viendo la entrada para [Stack Overflow en español en Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stackoverflow-in-spanish), es obvio que el sitio necesita mejorar el porcentaje de preguntas contestadas.

Pregunta: ¿alguien sabe cómo se calcula este porcentaje? En particular, quisiera saber si las preguntas *cerradas* forman parte del cálculo.

En otras palabras, quisiera saber hasta qué grado el sitio depende de la calidad de las preguntas para salir del beta.

Comment: @Mariano: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Excelente labor de investigacion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Porcentaje de preguntas respondidas

[Emmett](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/144066/emmett), antiguo desarrollador de Stack Exchange, detalló la fórmula en [Do the statistics show on Area 51 include also the closed questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/86976/209901):

> ```
> answeredPercentage = 100 - (total_unanswered / total_questions * 100);
> answerRatio = total_answers / (total_questions * answeredPercentage / 100);
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> Por lo tanto, `answeredPercentage` ("% answered" en la página de resumen) es de hecho "porcentaje de preguntas que han sido resueltas", ya sea con una respuesta o siendo cerradas.

O sea,

```
%Respondidas = ([Aceptadas] + [Con respuestas con puntaje > 0] + [Cerradas]) / [Preguntas]
```

Es decir que sí, **las preguntas cerradas juegan a favor**: cuentan como una pregunta respondida, sin importar el motivo del cierre. Asimismo, las preguntas eliminadas no cuentan.

Este query muestra el porcentaje de respondidas de SOes:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/530265/percent-answered-in-se-sites-or-answered-in-area51-statistics
  <sup>*(continuamente actualizado cada domingo ~3:00 UTC)</sup>

Código:

```sql
WITH Answers AS (
  -- unique answers with best score per question
  SELECT ParentId AS Id, MAX(Score) AS Score
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY ParentId
)
, Counts AS (
  SELECT
    -- Count for questions joined with answers
    COUNT(*) AS Asked,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0)) 
      AS AcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL AND A.Score > 0 AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0))
      AS PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS Closed
  FROM Posts Q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers A
    ON Q.Id = A.Id
  WHERE Q.PostTypeId = 1
)

SELECT 
  Asked, AcceptedNotClosed, PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed, Closed,
  (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) AS Answered,

  Cast(Cast(
    (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed)
    / CAST(Asked AS FLOAT)
    *100 as decimal(18,2)
  ) as varchar(5)) + ' %' AS "%Answered"
FROM Counts
```

---

### Graduación de un sitio

Depende mucho de la **calidad** e indirectamente del **tráfico**. Las condiciones para que un sitio se gradúe son principalmente cualitativas. Y eso no necesariamente está relacionado con el porcentaje de preguntas respondidas. No hay, ni habrá, una *fórmula* para determinar el punto de graduación. Hay objetivos mucho más importantes que son subjetivos: sentido de comunidad, automoderación, retención de usuarios, calidad de contenido, etc.

Las condiciones para la salud de un sitio están muy bien expresadas por [Ana♦](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/238110/ana) en [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/304899)

> 1. **Cuando un sitio comienza a recibir consistentemente 10 preguntas/día, lo consideraremos para graduación.**
> 2. Si el beta público no produce consistentemente contenido útil y le faltan usuarios que puedan moderar la comunidad, procesando reportes y
>      encargándose del spam, de modo de poder mantener el "[compórtate
>      bien](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)" de nuestro modelo, el sitio se cerrará.

Pero es muy clara al explicar que:

> Esto no está 100% automatizado. Los community managers estarán
>   revisando manualmente cómo le está yendo a cada comunidad
>   individualmente, y algunos sitios podrían graduarse más "temprano" o
>   más "tarde" de lo que sugiera su actividad de preguntas por día; pero
>   es una regla efectiva a grandes rasgos.

A lo que [Pops♦](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites#comment840141_257614) agrega:

> Hay muchos sitios y diferentes situaciones potenciales, por lo que
>   estaba siendo intencionalmente vago en la definición para mantenerlo
>   flexible... pero eso es lo que intentaba cubrir al decir que los
>   community managers serán quienes tomen la decisión final manualmente.

dando más detalle [luego](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites#comment840168_257614):

> La salud de la comunidad, con los privilegios tal cual quedan luego de la
>   graduación es un criterio importante: es algo que miramos en la
>   evaluación manual, y un posible motivo por el cual un sitio podría no
>   graduarse, a pesar de alcanzar las preguntas/día.

Y en cuanto al [tiempo hasta la graduación](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites#comment840247_257614):

> No hay un lapso estipulado de tiempo en el que un sitio está apto para
>   graduarse, pero pensamos en que por lo menos un año aproximadamente,
>   quizás un poquito menos. Lo de 90 días hasta la graduación es realmente
>   algo del pasado.

En concordancia, estos son algunos de los comentarios recopilados de diferentes publicaciones:

- [Joel Spolsky♠️](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/), refiriéndose al beta público y la graduación:

  > Un sitio de SE funciona sólo cuando tiene una masa crítica: suficientes personas que entran a cada hora para que las preguntas sean respondidas.
- [Shog9♦](//discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/10420/144602), refiriéndose a la cantidad de preguntas/día y si incluye o no a las preguntas cerradas:

  > Deberías concentrarte en hacer aquello que es bueno para el sitio y sus miembros, no en el número.
- [Ben Brocka](//discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/are-there-any-general-guidelines-how-to-improve-the-statistics-of-a-site?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment9533_5041) (♦ en [UX](//ux.stackexchange.com/)), acerca de si hay lineamientos para mejorar las estadísticas de un sitio:

  > Lo más importante es atraer y lograr el compromiso de expertos en el área. Cómo hacerlo, eso es más bien intrincado y depende de cada sitio.
- [Jon Ericson♦](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/279855/304899), acerca de las estadísticas en SE/sites:

  > Principalmente miro la cantidad de preguntas por día, lo cual es una medida certera de cuán listos están para la graduación.
  >   [...]
  >   Ocasionalmente, me resulta útil comparar la cantidad de visitas por día [...], algo específico de mi rol como community manager.
  >   [...]
  >   Para el caso general, las estadísticas no se comparan bien entre sitios.
  >   [...]
  >   De todos modos, encuentro más significativas las estadísticas [por etiqueta](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/225883/question-stats-by-tag?tag=%27java%27).
- [Jon Ericson♦](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271989/does-it-pay-to-spin-off-sites#comment97708_271990), hablando de la viabilidad de un sitio:

  > [...] evaluaremos si el sitio realmente está *expandiendo* la audiencia [versus dividiendo la de SO].

En conclusión, existen algunos lineamientos bien marcados, pero todo se resume en lograr que el sitio...

- [Joel Spolsky♠️](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/):

  > Haga de la Internet un mejor lugar para obtener respuestas de expertos a tus preguntas.

Comment: gracias por recopilar toda esta informacion sobre la graduacion

Comment: Jajaja, Joel Spolsky tiene picas en vez de diamante, Parece que anda flojo en el solitario.