# Ratio de respuestas por pregunta

Tags: discusión, estadísticas, fase-beta, area51

Estaba mirando en el [Area 51 de SOes](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) qué porcentaje llevábamos de Preguntas Contestadas y actualmente 73% :(

Pero respecto al ratio de Respuestas por Pregunta, me parece difícil en este sitio el que suba a 2.5 (2.5 respuestas por pregunta está bien, según Area 51).

En sitios como [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) es muy fácil ya que promueven las variedad de respuestas y tiene una media de 10 respuestas por pregunta . **¿Ese ratio es distinto dependiendo del sitio?**

Comment: Me parecería raro que el ratio de P/R en un SE de programación fuese mucho mayor que 1. En programación suele haber una solución satisfactoria para cada problema (aún con diferentes aproximaciones) y eso conlleva que una vez dada la solución satisfactoria suele ser poco útil dar otra solución satisfactoria con una aproximación diferente.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster exactamente es mi preocupacion. A poco que haya varias soluciones validas se puede marcar como demasiado amplia.

Comment: @lois6b uno de los factores pueden ser los nuevos usuarios; usualmente vienen por una respuesta (y la obtienen) pero no marcan la respuesta _no aceptan la respuesta_ en la página.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave eso es algo que no me habia parado a pensar pero no creo que afecte ya que el ratio mide el numero de respuestas, no el numero de aceptadas. Aceptada o no, cuenta para el ratio

Comment: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/25289/91740

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza este enlace es una muy buena información como se define "pregunta contestada", y indica que sería más claro de referirse a "pregunta atendida", por la razón que también incluye preguntas cerradas. Eso sin embargo añade a la pregunta, como se calcula el promedio de respuestas por pregunta. Eso considera preguntas cerradas y no borradas también? Una respuesta oficial sería muy útil.

Comment: @StefanNolde hay una pregunta más antigua inclusive, del 2011 o 2009, no recuerdo bien, pero tampoco tiene respuesta oficial. Es como si se lo reservaran.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si, recién lo vi siguiendo un en lace en la pregunta que compartiste, aparentemente no existe ninguna información oficial como se calcula exactamente la cuota de respuestas por pregunta. En el caso peor eso significa que para llegar a 2.5 respuestas en promedio, deberíamos tener una respuesta con 5 respuestas validas para cada pregunta cerrado. Con la manera que se maneja el tema de cierre, revisión y moderación  aquí en este momento, veo poca posibilidad que eso se puede conseguir.

Comment: Gracias @Stefan y Luiggi, me costó muchísimo llegar a ese número. Acá publiqué la versión en español con más info: [¿Cómo funciona la estadística “porcentaje de preguntas contestadas” en Area 51?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1279/127)... Y la verdad no tengo idea cómo se calcula R/P (intenté pero no llego al número).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Ese ratio es distinto dependiendo del sitio?

¡Por supuesto que depende de cada sitio!

### Respecto a la graduación

Supongo que tu pregunta está dirigida a la graduación del sitio. Las estadísticas de Area51 son más ilustrativas que certeras a la hora de evaluar la salud de un sitio. Funcionan como un indicador a muy grandes rasgos. Sin embargo, a la hora de evaluar una graduación, **no hay fórmulas, las condiciones son más bien cualitativas**.

Casos análogos al nuestro:

- Stack Overflow em Português [se graduó con 1.7 r/p](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese).
- Stack Overflow на русском [se graduó con 1.7 r/p](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian).

En este sentido, creo que es mucho más importante evaluar si hay preguntas que deberían tener más puntos de vista en las respuestas, o si deberíamos esperar respuestas que vayan más a fondo que las actuales. -En mi opinión, estamos muy bien en este aspecto.

En cuanto a las condiciones para la salud de un sitio frente a su graduación, recopilé diferentes respuestas y comentarios en [¿Cómo funciona la estadística “porcentaje de preguntas contestadas” en Area 51?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1279/127) (ver la segunda parte de la respuesta).

### Respecto a lo mejor para el sitio

Podemos pensar estrategias, o motivos por los que alguien agregue o no una respuesta más a una pregunta, pero este indicador está relacionado a una cuestión de fondo: **la cantidad de expertos en la comunidad**. A mayor cantidad, mayor será la probabilidad de ver respuestas diferentes (o más detalladas) a una misma pregunta.

Sigue siendo un indicador general para una característica cualitativa. Pero **cada día se suman más** expertos en cada tema. No creo que sea un aspecto para preocuparnos, sino todo lo contrario. No obstante, lo mejor que podemos hacer para mejorar esta y todas las métricas es publicitar el sitio e involucrar más usuarios activos.

Comment: estaba escribiendo un comentario sobre ".7 p/r." cuando vi tu edit ^^  gracias por tu respuesta, explicas muy bien la evaluacion de graduacion. y gracias por tu opinion *a lo mejor para el sitio*

Answer (score 4):

**Sin duda lo debe ser** (aun que no sé si eso se considera en la evaluación). Independiente si hay discriminación entre sitios distintos en la evaluación y la cuota de 2.5 esta definido para SOes o si es un valor general, no hacemos lo mejor para llegar a este cuota.

Me explico:

A mi me da la impresión que la cuota de respuestas por pregunta aquí esta un poco frenado por varios comportamientos comunes.

Algunos ejemplos que causan menos respuestas a preguntas:

**Siempre esperar una respuesta canónica y completa**

Por ejemplo en la pregunta [No me funciona el evento mouseclicked para menu item](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50321/no-me-funciona-el-evento-mouseclicked-para-menu-item) recibí el comentario (asertivo y razonable) que podría haber dado una respuesta más completa. Concuerdo, pero en este caso no fue mi intención de hacerlo. Porqué?

La pregunta fue muy corto y con poco contexto. Entonces dejé el comentario al OP que podría recibir mejores respuestas si sería capaz y dispuesto de dar un contexto más concreto (agregando código, documentando sus esfuerzos). Luego, para no hacerlo sentir que lo único que recibe en SO es crítica hacía su forma de preguntar,  le di una respuesta **mínima** para ser correcta y funcional.

Para recibir un mejor rato de buenas preguntas se podría también haber reaccionado en agregar otra respuesta que se refiere a la respuesta funcional en una manera como: "Agregando más informaciones a la respuesta X ..." dando más informaciones al contexto, la base teórica, más opciones posibles etc.

Así se crea una colección de respuestas que es de uso para una amplia cantidad de usuarios que se encuentran con la pregunta: A algunos les va importar la solución simple, otros van a disfrutar la respuesta más teórica, que les ayuda en su entendimiento.

**Ser demasiado exigente con la amplitud de una pregunta, cerrándolo como "demasiado amplio"**

Veo muchas veces que preguntas se cierren muy rápido, supuestamente siendo demasiado amplio, pero en casos en que existen buenas respuestas que no tienen que ser exageradamente extenso para ser útil. Si limitemos el sitio voluntariamente a preguntas que no tienen más que una o dos respuestas validas, nos condenemos a tener pocas respuestas. Este problema aumenta si la gente andan con el "dedo de gatillo suelto" para votar para abajo respuestas solamente porque no son tan "perfectas" como lo esperan, muchas veces más encima sin comentar la razón porque no lo encuentran útil, ni respondiendo con una pregunta propia que es (subjetivamente) mejor.

**Menospreciar respuestas simples o parciales, solamente porque existe una mejor respuesta o una más completa**

Cualquier respuesta correcta y apuntando al tema puede ayudar al usuario. Mientras tanto una respuesta una respuesta no esta falso, erróneo o peligroso, no tiene que ser una mala respuesta solamente porque no es tan formal que podríamos esperarlo de una documentación científica. Además cada pregunta tiene "clientes" de varios entornos y niveles de entendimiento. Si limito las respuestas "aceptables" a  "disertaciones", y voto todo para abajo que no cumple con este exigencia, pierdo valor del sitio para muchos novatos. En contrario deberíamos quedarnos mente abierto y respetar una variedad de niveles de información (mientras sea correcto) para no perder muchos novatos que probablemente disfrutan la opción de eligir la respuesta con complejidad adecuada a los que ellos en este momento pueden entender. Quizás después de implementarlo, vuelven más capacitados para entender la pregunta más canónica.

**Resumiendo,**

todo eso funciona mejor si evitemos de entrar en un espíritu de competencia sobre las preguntas, pero tratemos de trabajar más en equipo. Cada uno aporta con su conocimiento en la medida de su tiempo, sus ganas y lo que encuentra apropiado en el contexto del esfuerzo demostrado por el OP y se respetan respuestas que no son completas pero si "agregan valor" al asunto.

Falta únicamente agregar que eso es mi opinión y un ideal a que tato de apuntar yo mismo, pero como nadie es infalible tampoco quiero esperar que eso se puede implementar perfectamente sin errores. Sin embargo estoy convencido que abrir la mente a un poco más liberalismo en el manejo de preguntas y respuestas puede ser una buena manera para fomentar una mejor quota de respuestas de valor.

Comment: Me parece una muy buena respuesta, te agradezco el tiempo empleado. Pero la pregunta la contestas en la primera linea y el resto no tiene que ver con mi pregunta. Los motivos por los que una pregunta puede llegar a tener mas de una respuesta son interesantes pero yo solo pregunto si el ratio esperado del sitio en beta es distinto para cada tipo de sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Tu pusiste `discusión` como etiqueta, así asumí que la pregunta se dirige un poco a "debería ser". No te podría dar una respuesta (como ya he indicado) si en la evaluación de sitios existe una discriminación en contexto del tema de la plataforma. Respondí con tanto contexto porque creo que en un caso de discusión sobre el tema cuantas respuestas se esperan por pregunta hay que considerar tambien cuantas respuestas fomentemos (y como he planteado, no fomentemos muchos). Voy a aclarar.

Comment: Si, tienes razon y por eso di upvote. Tenemos que replantearnos mucho los motivos que tu mencionas si queremos prosperar.

Comment: Y quiero aprovecharme a dar las gracias a la persona que votó en contra a una respuesta en una pregunta de **discusión** sin dar una alternativa. Compruebe mi punto, eso es exactamente la actitud como limito la motivación para responder :) Por fin alguien que entiende el sofismo.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con Stefan. Lo del cierre de preguntas por "demasiado amplias" o "no está claro lo que se pregunta" es un problema. Y curiosamente a algunas de esas personas que son tan estrictas para cerrar preguntas luego les molesta que seas estricto al votar en sus respuestas (no va por ti Stefan). Respuesto a las respuestas yo creo que hay que ser estricto. De quien pregunta se puede esperar desconocimiento, por eso pregunta. Pero una respuesta con errores, grandes o pequeños, no debe recibir votos positivos. Aunque podría ser una idea contener unos días el negativo con los nuevos.

Comment: @StefanNolde bien dicho Stefan es algo que comentabamos en la tarde, deseamos atraer usuarios que quieran aportar, no personas que tengan miedo a realizarlo, espero algunos entiendan **Backpfeifengesicht!**

Answer (score 3):

Existen varios factores que he reconocido, incluso algunos los hemos comentado entre los integrantes de la comunidad, creo que esta comunidad esta conformada por desarrolladores de todos los niveles, algunos inician otros tal vez no desarrollan profesionalmente, algunos otros tal vez se acercan por curiosidad.

> En sitios como CodeGolf es muy fácil ya que promueven las variedad de
>   respuestas y tiene una media de 10 respuestas por pregunta .

Actualmente pudiera ser dificil ya que de la gran cantidad de usuarios que conforman esta comunidad, un porcentaje tal vez no optimo se atreven a responder o incluso preguntar.

Esto se puede notar cuando se agrega una pregunta que implica preguntas que se basan principalmente en opiniones, varios usuarios por primera vez expresan su opinion en ocasiones, sin embargo en ocasiones sus respuestas son hechas trizas por desarrolladores experimentados que en lugar de opinar de una forma amable o ayudar, empiezan a tener una actitud no muy adecuada ya que generalmente buscan que otros usuarios agreguen respuestas de un profesional.

Un 73% necesita un poco mas de trabajo para llegar al 90% aceptable.

**La única forma acertada de sobresalir es trabajar en equipo,** somos aproximadamente 25,092 usuarios, espero aumente el numero de usuarios que respondan.