# Relajar el requisito de concreción de las preguntas

Tags: discusión

(Relacionada: [¿Somos demasiados exigentes con las preguntas de los usuarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466/somos-demasiados-exigentes-con-las-preguntas-de-los-usuarios))

Hay mucha polémica por preguntas que se cierran porque "Existen muchas formas de codificar lo que el OP indica" y "No habría manera de escoger una verdadera e imparcial respuesta correcta":

[¿Vamos a negar la posibilidad de preguntar al que no sabe nada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471/vamos-a-negar-la-posibilidad-de-preguntar-al-que-no-sabe-nada)

Sin embargo, tal vez haya que relajar un poco este requisito *si consideramos que es aceptable que una pregunta tenga varias respuestas*. Yo lo considero, y de hecho opino que:

- Enriquecería la comunidad, porque da más oportunidades de participar.
- Se pueden dar varios enfoques al mismo problema.
- Da la opción a la comunidad de valorar cuál de todas las respuestas es mejor.

Lo que no puede ser es que nos lamentemos de que hay muy pocas respuestas por pregunta (v. [Ratio de respuestas por pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430/ratio-de-respuestas-por-pregunta)) mientras cerramos preguntas por ser «demasiado amplias». Ya no estoy pensando en graduar el sitio o no, estoy pensando en la riqueza de la comunidad.

¿Opiniones?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, sobre todo si consideramos que el contenido de buena calidad es ínfimo en castellano. Creo que esSO puede ser pionero y motivador de que haya cada vez más contenido de calidad en castellano y que un espíritu restrictivo ahogaría esa posibilidad. Aquí explico con más detalle el por qué, partiendo desde una experiencia reciente: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1478/29967

Comment: Muy buen punto lo del ratio de respuestas por pregunta. Una buena medida de cómo el cierre por "demasiado amplio" está perjudicando las posibilidades de salir de beta.

Answer (score 4):

Siempre se ha sido mas relajado en estas normas en el sitio español que el original y eso (salvo excepciones concretas) es un fact.

Asimismo se toman muy en serio las preguntas cerradas sin comentario y constantemente se ha pedido en varias publicaciones ayudar mas a los usuarios dando la oportunidad de ayudar a plantear bien la pregunta en lugar de votar negativo+cierre e irse. Eso es un fact también en los reportes diarios que recibo.

Como comento en [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/861/7242) nos tenemos que tomar en serio las colas de revisión donde la mayoría de casos que comentas van a parar.

No soy partidario de relajar aun mas esas normas ya que entonces el sitio se llenaría de preguntas con mala calidad y eso es algo que no queremos (como comunidad).

Lo que encuentro correcto es ante casos específicos que no creáis que se hayan 'tratado' bien es traerlos en meta o bien realizar un reporte para revisarlos, siempre es de agradecer las ganas de mejorar el sitio.

Des de mi punto de visto el sitio funciona como debe: La comunidad elige y crea sus normas a partir de la base de la que salio.