# ¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Vox Populi?

Tags: discusión, votos

Como ya hemos discutido muchas veces (por ejemplo, en [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/324)) votar es importante porque es una de las formas de determinar si las preguntas son correctas y concretas o no.

El sitio usa los votos para segmentar las búsquedas, y más allá de las preguntas canónicas que llevan muchos votos por sí mismas, hay montones de preguntas que merecen la atención cuando uno busca una solución a un problema.

Tenemos que ser responsables en cuanto a la forma de votar, y tampoco desparramar votos porque sí, pero no debemos penalizar a las preguntas que suenan triviales, solo porque son triviales. Si la pregunta está bien formulada, y sobre todo si merece una respuesta, quiere decir que quien preguntó, hizo un trabajo responsable.

En [Haz +1 a las preguntas que respondes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/849/324), también aquí en Meta, una de las respuestas pide por favor, que si ves una pregunta o respuesta interactúes con ella, ya sea votándola si consideras que está bien o mal, editándola, o comentando respecto de ella.

Votar es una muestra de confianza también hacia los nuevos usuarios. Penalizar con votos negativos a usuarios nuevos porque sus preguntas son simples o triviales no es algo que deberíamos hacer, pero sí recompensar a aquellos que hacen preguntas triviales, pero ponen su esfuerzo en tratar de darse a entender de la mejor manera posible.

Los votos dan privilegios, y los usuarios con privilegios pueden ayudar mejor a mantener el sitio limpio y claro.

¿Se les ocurre alguna otra forma de mejorar el caudal de votos faltantes que tenemos en las preguntas y respuesta?

Comment: de hecho hace algun tiempo [hice una pregunta parecida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3757/premiar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios-que-elaboren-una-buena-pregunta)

Comment: No entiendo en qué medida una pregunta así, tipo anuncio, puede tener una respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Totalmente de acuerdo con gbianchi y fedorqui.  Claramente hay que "machacar" esto mucho más, debemos generar la cultura del voto (+1/-1).

`¿Se les ocurre alguna otra forma de mejorar el caudal de votos faltantes que tenemos en las preguntas y respuesta?`

Ideas:

- El voto en general es una acción, que creo, puede no ser tan "visible" para usuarios noveles. Una forma de visibilizar esto, sería "publicitar" el voto positivo, sobre todo en el caso de los nuevos usuarios, no solo votar, sino dejar un mensaje tipo:

> Oye [autor], te he dado un +1 por que tu pregunta me pareció muy útil y bien formulada, invito al resto de la comunidad a hacer lo mismo. Sigue así!

O bien:

> Que buena respuesta [autor]! te he dado un +1, invito a todos a hacer lo mismo.

- Otra posibilidad, es "explotar" el ego, construyendo una publicación tipo ranking, mensual, aquí en meta, por ejemplo con los nuevos "Top" Votantes. Digo los "nuevos" por que a nivel histórico, pienso que hay mucha menos renovación de usuarios. Ni hablar si hubiera además algún incentivo por parte de SO ;-).

Comment: Pues oye Patricio, te he dado un +1 porque la respuesta me parece llena de buenas ideas que desde ya pongo en práctica :)

Comment: me has hecho sonreir @fedorqui

Comment: Bueno chicos, no exageremos, ja ja..

Comment: Me parece muy buena la idea que todos proponen!, pero me queda la duda si estas acciones entrarán en conflicto con las recomendaciones sobre [cómo usar los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): _"... Dejar cumplidos que realmente no añaden nueva información..."_

Comment: @JheymanMejia, es cierto, tal vez es un poco rebuscado, pero si aceptamos la hipótesis que planteo: que la acción de votar no es del todo "visble" para el usuario novel, agregar un comentario como este en realidad agregaría más información. Digo, hoy, ya es bastante frecuente y aceptado los comentarios a la hora de votar negativamente, que representa en definitiva  un cumplido en negativo ;-)

Comment: @JheymanMejia si esto es un campaña, pasados unos dias podemos ir haciendo limpieza.. no lo veo mal...

Comment: El ranking es un arma de doble filo.. la otra me parece genial... lo he hecho muchas veces para usuarios primerizos, por ejemplo recalcando que hagan el tour, pero que su pregunta estaba muy bien formulada...

Comment: Yo desde hace mucho cuando veo que una respuesta es buena e incluso el autor comenta que le ha ayudado, suelo poner un comentario del estilo _[op], si esta respuesta te ha ayudado considera votarla positivamente y aceptarla, para indicar así a futuros usuarios que esta es la respuesta correcta a tu problema_ Os invito a hacer lo mismo a todos

Comment: Muy interesante

Answer (score 32):

Es necesario votar mas. Salgamos de nuestra trinchera y votemos las cosas por su nivel: si vemos algo bien formulado, votémoslo positivamente; si vemos algo bien respondido, votémoslo positivamente. No puede ser que haya preguntas con varias respuestas y sin ningún voto por aquello de "no voto a la otra no sea que aparezca arriba y la mía ya no se vea". A la larga, el contenido bueno debe ir para arriba y agradeceremos que así sea cuando nos enfrentemos con un problema y queramos saber qué determinaron los expertos que era correcto.

Hace algunos años en Spanish.SE tuvimos un debate similar. De hecho, lo hemos tenido varias veces hasta conseguir una mayor implicación. Un elemento objetivo de juicio es *cuánto se vota* y para ello el insigne usuario Gilles [nos dio en Meta Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/378/1674) una buena herramienta para ello: [una consulta de SEDE para mirar cuánto vota cada sitio](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/195762/average-number-of-votes-on-all-sites), teniendo en cuenta todas las publicaciones no borradas.

Hice la consulta con datos de 9 de junio de 2019 y saqué los datos de los sitios más importantes y de los lugares más prominentes (los primeros, los últimos). Tras tabular y ordenando por número de votos por publicación, vemos lo siguiente:

```
#   Site                PostCount     VoteCount   VoteRatio  UpVoteRatio    DownVoteRatio   Up/Down Ratio
1   SE.Skeptics            20.952       400.210     19,1013    17,0764      2,0249           8,4334
4   SE.Meta               222.216     2.589.748     11,6542     9,279       2,3752           3,9066
5   SE.Scifi              157.842     1.756.584     11,1287    10,2719      0,8568          11,9885
6   SE.Politics            26.520       275.854     10,4017     8,7463      1,6554           5,2834
51  SE.Sports              12.015        62.114      5,1697     4,3574      0,8123           5,3641
68  SE.Russian             13.024        59.522      4,5702     4,2761      0,2941          14,541
89  SE.Spanish             20.674        84.400      4,0824     3,8587      0,2237          17,2486
125 StackOverflow      44.920.402   138.861.871      3,0913     2,7336      0,3577           7,6422
147 StackOverflow.Pt      283.655       708.026      2,4961     2,0787      0,4174           4,9804
166 SE.Wordpress          215.873       399.003      1,8483     1,4607      0,3877           3,7677
167 StackOverflow.Ja       41.350        71.577      1,731      1,5414      0,1896           8,1309
168 SE.Magento.           195.975       338.312      1,7263     1,6008      0,1255          12,7598
169 StackOverflow.Ru      576.259       968.261      1,6803     1,3773      0,303            4,5461
170 SE.Rus                 49.792        77.191      1,5503     1,4186      0,1316          10,7759
171 StackOverflow.Es      197.060       282.543      1,4338     1,1203      0,3135           3,5734
172 SE.Expressionengine    27.967        39.475      1,4115     1,3637      0,0478          28,5472
173 SE.Sharepoint         199.955       277.444      1,3875     1,2826      0,1049          12,2293
```

Como vemos claramente, SOes es el 171.º de 173, o sea el antepenúltimo, en número de votos por publicación, con apenas 1,4. Los Stack Overflow japoneses y rusos andan a la par, si bien SOpt promedia un voto más por publicación. Además, nuestra tendencia a votar negativo es bastante potente y aparecemos como 8.º por la cola en la ratio votos positivos por cada voto negativo.

(Como nota, en Spanish.SE hemos pasado de 3,6 votos positivos por publicación a 4,1 en cuatro años)

Datos históricos, de momento mostrando una <s>no-evolución</s> involución (siempre aparecemos como penúltimos, solo superando a Sharepoint y bajando a medida que se crean nuevos sitios):

| Fecha | Posición | PostCount | VoteCount | VoteRatio | UpVoteRatio | DownVoteRatio | Up/Down Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/6/2019 | 171 | 197.060 | 282.543 | 1,4338 | 1,1203 | 0,3135 | 3,5734 |
| 21/7/2019 | 171 | 203.671 | 295.206 | 1,4494 | 1,131 | 0,3184 | 3,5525 |
| 8/12/2020 | 174 | 293.317 | 408.851 | 1,3939 | 1,0854 | 0,3085 | 3,5179 |
| 22/6/2021 | 174 <sub>(penúltimo)</sub> | 322798 | 446.607 | 1,3835 | 1,0695 | 0,314 | 3,4062 |
| 25/6/2022 | 177 <sub>(penúltimo)</sub> | 367.774 | 493.998 | 1,3432 | 1,0341 | 0,3091 | 3,3459 |

Añado: en [una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2000/83) a su pregunta *Métricas interesantes para el sitio*, el siempre añorado Mariano puso tres consultas interesantes:

> [Votos de usuarios de mayor reputación](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/670814/votos-de-usuarios-de-mayor-reputacion?TOP=500&ActivoHace=90&RepMin=200&RepMax=0&PostsMin=50&VotosMin=0&UVMin=0&DVMin=0&VRepMin=0&VRepMax=0&VdayMin=0&VdayMax=0#resultSets)

en ella vemos cuánto votan los usuarios con mayor reputación. Yo soy el primero en hacerlo poco y, en general, muy poca gente supera los 2-3 votos por día.

Comment: Necesito darte una recompensa por tanto amor... <3

Comment: Tus datos son geniales fedorqui. Sobre tu comentario _"no voto a la otra no sea que aparezca arriba y la mía ya no se vea"_ cabe aclarar que existe una medalla que promueve el comportamiento contrario, el juego limpio, y se llama precisamente [Espíritu Deportivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship)

Comment: Estos datos son demoledores. Tenemos el dedo muy ligero para votar negativamente, y no tanto para votar positivamente. Deberíamos plantearnos que hacer para solucionarlo...

Comment: @Pikoh seguro que conoces mejor el panorama que yo, que no frecuento el chat, pero mi impresión es que tendemos a dos-tres expertos por etiqueta, más personas que preguntan cosas muy puntuales y poco generalizables. Esas preguntas son flojas y los dos-tres expertos que contestan puede que "luchen" por tener el +15 de la aceptación, por lo que no se votan entre ellos para no decantar la balanza. Algo así pasaba en las etiquetas que frecuentaba en SO (bash, awk, sed, unix...) y era un poco cansino.

Comment: @fedorqui en el chat no se suele hablar del tema, pero si es posible que suceda lo que dices en muchas etiquetas. Por ello probablemente se creó la medalla ["Espiritu deportivo"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) ;) Por cierto... **solo hay 12 concedidas**

Comment: @Pikoh pues ya tenemos el siguiente reto a proponer: *¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Espíritu deportivo?*

Comment: Hablando de ello, la medalla "[Electorado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate)" también puede contribuir con la discusión, apoyando el uso de los votos por parte de los usuarios

Comment: @fedorqui Es muy complicado conseguir la de "Espiritu deportivo" basicamente porque la media de respuestas por pregunta es muy baja, como ya se comentó en algún sitio (vi la métrica en algun lugar hace tiempo pero no recuerdo dónde), aunque estaria de lujo incentivar tambien el publicar más respuestas y no limitarse a una por pregunta

Comment: @fedorqui Lo encontré: [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430/ratio-de-respuestas-por-pregunta)

Comment: @Marc buen punto, pues efectivamente consiste en votar otras respuestas y que la tuya tenga puntuación de al menos 1. Sin embargo, creo que lo interesante más que la medalla en sí es intentar llegar a ella, reconociendo las otras respuestas buenas con un +1 (o -1 cuando sean incorrectas). Porque en qué ámbito podemos votar con mejor conocimiento de causa que en el que solemos contestar.

Comment: @fedorqui Totalmente de acuerdo, es una actitud muy sana el votar otras buenas respuestas aun habiendo respondido tu mismo con una solución, a parte de lo que puedas aprender de los demás.

Comment: Me hace mal cada vez que editas esto.. lo voy a hablar con los CM...

Comment: me quedo con esto: _Además, nuestra tendencia a votar negativo es bastante potente y aparecemos como 8.º por la cola en la ratio votos positivos por cada voto negativo_ hace día comentaba que SOes; es menos permisivo, si lo comparamos con otros sitios. o podemos decir que en otras lenguas/sitios saben hacen mejores preguntas...

Answer (score 6):

¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Vox Populi?

No, ni la quiero; ni la merezco.

Buenas noches a todos.

A riesgo de meterme en camisa de once varas, habiendo leído media docena de hilos referentes a votos, medallas, reputación, etc., y con la certeza de que soy el menos adecuado para exponer aquí razones de peso de si es o no conveniente votar, cómo hacerlo, etc., me parece conveniente mostrar un punto de vista de un recién llegado.

Parto de dos premisas: las medallas, la reputación, y, por supuesto el voto, que otorga tanto medallas como méritos, y es clave para promocionar buenas preguntas y respuestas,así como para penalizar las malas, son, a mi corto entender, la esencia del funcionamiento de sitio. Segunda premisa: ni soy programador, ni informático, ni si quiera sé programar. Y mis pocos y torpes intentos por hacerlo me confirman precisamente que no es mi fuerte, ni mucho menos. Podéis buscarme en twitter por @*LuseR*, sobran más adjetivos.

Dicho lo anterior, al grano: me "he ganado", por entrar en el sitio, una medalla, por preguntar, otra, por poner una foto en el perfil otra... ¿Las necesito? Si lo que que quería era resolver una duda... Digo más: si vengo de cuándo en cuándo, por leer algo y aprender una pizca de bash, necesito conocer la estructura del sitio, el funcionamiento de las promociones de los moderadores, otorgar votos a respuestas cuyo código no soy capaz de interpretar? rotundamente NO.

Si fuese egoísta (no lo soy) hubiera llegado, propuesto mi pregunta sin haberme leído cómo preguntar, esperar a que algún penitente me resolviese el ejercicio para no suspender (ojo, que ya peino canas y mis exámenes los pasé hace mucho tiempo), y marchado sin siquiera haber dado las gracias. Y el ser humano, por desgracia, es así. También nos matamos entre nosotros y aquí seguimos, sin dramas.

Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia.

Eso requiere tiempo, voluntad, y conocimientos para que el voto sea justo (de ésto último yo no tengo ni cero coma). El otro día volví a donar a wikipedia, licencia CC, porque, o colaboramos o el sitio se cae por su propio peso. Me siento en la obligación de donar, porque me he pasado cientos de horas aprendiendo de sus artículos. Pero donamos sólo el 1 % de los usuarios. ¿El 99 % de los usuarios de SO se leen cómo preguntar, por qué es importante el voto, qué es la reputación, o como funciona el sistema de medallas? Seguramente sí cuando el sitio nació como refugio de profesionales; pero ya es "vox populi", ya corrió la voz de que es el mejor sitio para resolver dudas informáticas, y vengo, me registro, pregunto qué ratón es el más adecuado para mi portatil azul, y espero que estos señores tan amables me contesten con una certeza incontestable (son informáticos, oiga). Una vuelta por la etiqueta Linux lo confirma; la de windows ni me planteo ojearla. Cierto también que habrá grandísimas preguntas y respuestas en etiquetas como SQL, PERL, C... Pero si me doblega bash, esas ni me las planteo.

Somos así.

Haz +1 a las preguntas que respondes.

De nuevo, yo personalmente no me aventuro: mis conocimientos no llegan para responder las preguntas interesantes y bien planteadas que entran en el sitio. Sí, he contestado un par de preguntas (¡Yo, yo, que esa me la sé!). Pero  [Como exlciur directorio al empaquetar con tar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274990/como-exlciur-directorio-al-empaquetar-con-tar) no es estrictamente una pregunta de programación. (Ojo, no critico la pregunta, las mías no podrán ir mucho más allá; sólo expongo un hecho). Si respondí fue porque ¡Yo, yo, que esa me la sé!, y por colaborar con la comunidad que a mi me ha ayudado previamente. (También hay gente así, mire usted). Pero si la pregunta no es de programación, ¿por qué votarla?

Eso se lo dejo a @fedorqui, o a @patricio moracho, que sin ser yo un lince, y sin contarles las medallas, ya deduje en mi segunda visita al sitio que son profesionales del oficio, que saben de lo que hablan, y que, con reputación o sin ella su palabra es palabra de dios. Así funcionan todos los foros desde que los inventaron en Roma.

Del voto negativo a los recién llegados ni hablo. Si no se molestan ni en leer un manual, pegarse un ratillo con la consola (bash es la mía), con no resoolverles el ejercicio llega. Que también tienen el rincon del vago, que se molesten un poquito. Se les enlazan las normas y a otra cosa.

Asumo, de nuevo, que el voto es necesario para el funcionamiento del sitio, pero aquí sigue SO con cada día más usuarios y muy buenas consultas y geniales respuestas (al menos eso me han dicho, que yo de picar código ni idea, pero mi vecino es informátivo y eso dice).

> debemos generar la cultura del voto (+1/-1).

Por supuesto, sobradamente se han expuesto las razones, pero a mi, y supongo que a muchos otros, es una responsabilidad que me abruma. Como me abruma haber acumulado media docena de medallas por absolutamente nada (vale, son de bronce, que las de oro habŕa que sudarlas, pero REGALADAS NO TIENEN VALOR ALGUNO). Y las mías en concreto (allá cada cual con las suyas), no son merecidas (venga, dejadme una, que me hace ilu, pero el resto dejad que me las gane a pulso; y si no llego al listón, pues me quedo sin ella, que el sueldo ya lo gano por otro lado, tampoco es que se me quite el pan).
Así me siento yo, en serio, con tanto agasajo.

> El voto en general es una acción, que creo, puede no ser tan "visible" para usuarios noveles.

Incontestable, @Patricio . Te compro el discurso (pero no te lo voto, que el voto es cosa seria. Además, el voto ha de ser privado per se. No voy yo aquí a andar cascando si voto a PP o a PSOE, a Podemos o a VOX ... Populi... Uisss, otra medalla.

Ahora en serio, te explico por qué no te voto:

> Otra posibilidad, es "explotar" el ego, construyendo una publicación tipo ranking, mensual, aquí en meta, por ejemplo con los nuevos "Top" Votantes.

Cuidadín con eso: explotar el ego es abrir la caja de Pandora. Cuando yo era moderador de hfkjaff en la red mindforge, por un @ vi a un par sacarse los ojos. Ego, desafortunadamente, es los que nos sobra (mira yo mismo, con qué soltura me he encallado ya no en camisa de once varas, si no de setenta veces siete: es lo que tiene estar solo en casa delante del portátil, que uno se desata sin freno alguno).

> Que a partir de un cierto número de reputación, los usuarios puedan valorar las puntuaciones según unos parámetros:Calidad, trivialidad, complejidad,nunca antes preguntado en SOEs, pregunta wiki....

@David_helo , no me lo pongas más difícil que me doy de baja y exijo la devolución de la cuota...

Si yo entro aquí a leer, a aprender, a preguntar si ya no me da más la cabeza para pegarme con la consola o buscar soluciones en la web, que mañana madrugo y ya es tarde. Eso, en mi humilde opinión, es para moderadores del sitio. Yo pregunto, con miedo por si mi ignorancia es motivo de sorna, y si alguien tiene a bien ayudarme se lo agradezco (muchos ni eso, y de trolls que encima se ponen bordes porque un moderador les da un toque está la web llena). Así somos.

Y aquel espŕitu primero de SO, sitio de soporte de desarrolladores para desarrolladores, quedó hace tiempo en la cuneta. Prueba de ello es que yo mismo esté posteando esta enorme chapa aquí, cuando debería estar viendo las noticias con la evolución del incendio de Ávila. No digo que esos programadores no sigan por aquí, lo que digo es que somos muchos más lusers que BOFHs. Y para que un sistema funcione, al luser se le otorgan los privilegios mínimos necesarios para su desempeño laboral. La democracia es una falacia. No puedo tener yo la misma capacidad de votar si una respuesta es buena o mala que @fedorqui . Es evidente.

Y así es como yo lo veo. Cierto que es la opinión de un recién llegado, que solo ha percibido la punta del iceberg de toda la buena documentación que existe por aquí, del funcionamiento del sitio y del valor del voto. Seguramente, la opinión menos importante. La de un luser cualquiera. Por eso no quiero ni medallas, ni responsabilidades con el voto.

Mi intención primera era dar una ligera opinión desde el asiento de un recién llegado, para que la contrastáseis con vuestra experiencia acumulada: a veces los árboles no nos dejan ver el bosque. Pero ya os digo, aquí solo, se envalentona uno y saca su Dr. Jekyll (por ego que no sea, oiga).

Aquí lo dejo; para ser el que menos tengo que opinar la he echado larga...

Por supuesto, si mi respuesta se considera fuera de sitio, borradla, o hacédmelo saber y la elimino. Pero leedme.

Gracias por todo.

Edito: perdón si mi lenguaje suena sarcástico. Lo soy, y mucho, no sé explicarme de otra manera.

Comment: Bienvenido!!! siento decirte que por tomarte la molestia de contestar, y tomarte la molestia de escribir a esta hora un sabado.. y tomarte la molestia de leer a todos los otros usuarios, eres tan desarrollador como nosotros. A vos puede gustarte o no las acciones ludicas del sitio. Pero el problema es otro. Esas acciones ludicas llevan a decirnos en quien podemos confiar y quien no. Patricio, fedo, pikoh, alvaro y muchos otros tienen mucha reputación por algo. Porque son confiables. Y la manera de que sean confiables es con votos. (sigue)

Comment: Tal vez vos no puedas votar todas sus publicaciones. Ni siquiera te estamos pidiendo eso. Lo que pedimos, es que aquellos usuarios que saben de determinadas cosas y tienen la capacidad de hacerlo, evaluen las publicaciones, tanto preguntas como respuesta. Tenes varias respuestas en preguntas con 0 votos. Si consideraste que la pregunta merecia una respuesta, no parecio entonces que tambien merecia un voto de confianza a quien la escribio? Sobre eso estamos hablando.. confianza.. no si la pregunta es la mejor del planeta, si no si es clara y se entiende. (sigue)

Comment: No te metiste en un camisa, te tiraste a la pileta, con todos los flotadores. Un programador no tiene porque ser un experto con 20 años de trayectoria. Puede ser cualquier persona que tenga la intencion de hacer algo. y vos claramente la tenes.

Comment: Y meta es un lugar para discutir, charlar, hablar o lo que te guste. Y todo comentario, dentro del respeto, es bienvenido... Igual, no me queda claro cual es tu problema.. Te molesta el aspecto ludico del sitio? nadie te obliga a votar. Ni siquiera te obligaron a registrarte para preguntar o contestar! Todo lo que hiciste, lo hiciste porque quisiste.

Comment: Y para peor.. de vez en cuando, el sitio nos pone sombreros en las fotos por hacer cosas.. No es necesario que participes en nada del sitio que no te interese.. pero si no votaramos las cosas que se hacen bien.. como sabriamos en que creer?

Comment: Ah.. y no se porque pensas que la pregunta sobre tar no es de programación.. es una herramienta que se usa para comprimir, y tal vez la estoy ejecutando desde un script.. o desde un programa en python, perl, c, c#, java o el lenguaje que quieras... A veces el contexto influye...

Comment: Como señala gbianchi el objetivo del voto no es contribuir con el ego de las personas sino para indicarle a los nuevos visitantes cual es la pregunta que tiene más confianza por parte de la comunidad, ademas la cantidad de puntaje es una forma de determinar el tiempo y esfuerzo invertido en el sitio, y como recompensa a ello obtienes más privilegios.

Comment: En el caso de SO tenemos una cultura y experiencia en la moderación por lo que las discusiones sin sentido son minimizadas ya que la comunidad es la que interviene en ello, obviamente hay casos excepcionales pero son mínimos, en general siempre hay una discusión alturada.

Comment: Todas las acciones de SO son voluntarias, asi que si no deseas votar entonces no votes. Si no deseas participar en otras actividades no participes. Algunas medallas son solo para notar que el usuario conoce algo nuevo, pero otras sirven para indicar que el usuario contribuyo al sitio con acciones como: ediciones que mejoren las preguntas, señalar SPAM o actitudes negativas como los throlls, etc que sin esas acciones SO no sería lo que es hoy.

Comment: Buenas noches. Os lei recién publicáteis, pero aún no pude sentarme hasta ahora a contestar. @gbianchi, eyllanesc, gracias por vuestras palabras. No era mi intención centrar el hilo en mi, sino dar unas pistas sobre lo que a cualquier usuario de SO podría desmotivar para votar, participar, etc. Evidentemente, si yo lo escribo, mis razones serán las resaltadas (cada uno tendrá las suyas), pero, reitero, mi intención no era centrar el debate en guardabosques. Expuse varias razones por las que soy reacio a votar, las mías (porque éstas sí las conozco) y alguna otra que imagino (sigue)

Comment: Sigo pensando que los méritos se deben conseguir con mayor o menor esfuerzo, e intuyo que tal cantidad de medallas "anestesia" al usuario de su valor (a mi y a muchos). En cuanto a participar más en el voto, razones de baja participación expuse varias (las mías y otras), y habrá tantas como usuarios. ¿Habéis pensado en hacer una encuesta al respecto? Conocer las motivaciones es un paso fundamental en cualquier proceso de mejora de resultados (en este caso elevar la participación). Claro que, por experiencia, sé que si no nos molestamos en hacer un clic en el voto, mucho menos lo haremos (sigue

Comment: contestando una encuesta. Saludos, lo dicho, gracias. (Pd: no os contesto a las preguntas que me planteáis precisamente por no centrar el hio en @guardabosques, sino en ese usuario etéreo que puede ser cualquiera). Si realmente os interesa despejar esas dudas sobre mi, puedo hacerlo en privado.

Comment: @GuardabosqueS Gracias por tomarte el tiempo. Tene en cuenta que este es un sitio publico, y no existe lo privado aqui. Por lo cual, toda duda o consulta es publica. Centrar el debate en un caso no es malo, porque estamos cubriendo bases de lo que podrian ser muchos. Las preguntas y cuestionamientos que te hicimos, siguen estando vivas, y si tenes ganas, respondelas. Y si no, no lo hagas, como ya dijimos, nadie obliga a nada aca.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo a ti, @gbianchi , por tus palabras, y al resto de moderadores por el trabajo que desempeñan en el sitio. Reitero que no pretendo monopolizar el hilo con mis motivaciones; sin embargo, si es que esa encuesta que más arriba propuse se llevase a caso, no dudes que me tomaré mi tiempo en contestar. Saludos.

Comment: Es muy interesante lo que escribes, claramente es un punto de vista que no contemplaba. Resumiendo, corrígeme si me equivoco, no votas, por que no te sientes calificado para hacerlo. La verdad, es un buen punto, de hecho, ahora que lo pienso, yo tampoco voto en temas en los que no tenga un mínimo de conocimiento. Es una actitud responsable.

Comment: Tal vez la discusión se fue más para el lado de la reputación que generan los votos, pero la idea inicial es fomentar el uso de los votos como forma de perfeccionar el contenido, buenas e interesantes preguntas obtienen más votos, buenas y correctas respuesta también. Más puntos, más confianza en el contenido. Esa es la idea original de esta pregunta. ¿Y quiénes pueden votar? Todos. SO, no tiene un sistema de voto calificado (lo cual me parece lo mejor, aunque a veces pueda llegar a cuestionarse), ¿Se puede no votar? claro que sí, no hay ninguna obligación a hacerlo.

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que puedo decirte, es que si estás en SOes, no importa la forma en que participes, si has escrito alguna vez un `Hola mundo!`, si estás haciendo un `man bash`, no veo por que no considerarte a ti mismo un programador, sobre todo si es algo que te gusta. He leído tus preguntas y respuestas y la verdad que están más que bien, son buenos aportes. Tal vez en algún momento sientas la necesidad de dejar tu opinión con un voto o tal vez eso nunca ocurra.

Comment: Y para desmitificar un poco la reputación particular de los usuarios, te cometo una triste historia: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4192/no-votemos-positivamente-por-la-reputaci%c3%b3n-votemos-el-contenido

Comment: Había leído ese hilo, @PatricioMoracho, gracias en todo caso. Y muchas gracias por tus halagos, me agasajas demasiado... Claro que he escrito un hola mundo, pero tendría que revisar apuntes para volverlo a hacer :)). ayy, el voto... Si entiendo perfectamente la dinámica del sitio: buenas respuestas obtendrán más votos y promocionarán esas preguntas. La idea es buena, pero, reitero, la democracia es una falacia. En política por supuesto, y en SO asumo que también. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma de potenciar el voto, es darle una importancia que actualmente no tiene.

No se que disparatadas serán las ideas, o si se aleja mucho de lo que se busca, pero ahí las dejo:

Por ejemplo:

- Cuando yo monitoreo una etiqueta, dentro de ella puedo filtrar o por "Voto" o por "Sin responder". ¿Que utilidad tiene filtrar por voto si me sale una publicación del 2017 Respondida como primera? ¿Porque no filtrar "Sin comentario" y que aparezcan ordenadas por votos y así dedicar mi tiempo a esas preguntas que son buenas?
- Que a partir de un cierto número de reputación, los usuarios puedan valorar las puntuaciones según unos parámetros:Calidad, trivialidad, complejidad,nunca antes preguntado en SOEs, pregunta wiki.... (y que los resultados(SOLO RESULTADOS) solo sean públicos para estos usuarios)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para los usuarios con bajo privilegio, aparezca este "7,8" al lado de la pregunta, llamándole la atención ya que la pregunta ha conseguido un notable basado en 126 opiniones.

- Aprovechar las medallas que tienen algunos expertos en ciertos lenguajes, para darles un gran poder. Que puedan valorar como útiles las preguntas y que aparezca algo así:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma, debido a que dos grandes expertos en la materia han dicho que es útil, mucha gente querrá intentar verla y responderla.

Comment: Estas ideas serian genial.. si no fuera porque pedis cambios a nivel general de red.. Cualquier herramienta extra, implica no solo cambiarla para nosotros, si no para todo stack exchange. Me gustan las ideas.. sigamos construyendo, en lo posible con lo que tenemos a mano

Comment: Este tipo de cosas ya se ha propuesto muchas veces en SO y siempre se ha descartado. Supongo que entre otras razones, porque sería dar mas valor a los votos de unos usuarios con respecto a los otros.

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de la medalla Vox Populi tenemos otras dos relacionadas con los votos que me gustaría destacar:

- [Sufragio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage) (bronce), otorgada 322 veces

  > Utilizar 30 votos en un día
- [Electorado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) (oro), otorgada 58 veces

  > Votar en 600 preguntas y que el 25 % o más del total de votos esté en las preguntas.

Me parece que como comunidad deberíamos felicitar a los usuarios que obtengan estas medallas, particularmente la de Electorado, quizás hacerlo una vez cada trimestre.