# No votemos positivamente por la reputación, votemos el contenido!

Tags: discusión, votos

Antes que nada, el aviso:

> Por favor no votemos positivamente por la reputación sino por el contenido

Paso a contarles una triste historia real, ayer Diego Avila publica [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271374/seleccion-entre-fechas-mysql/271378#271378), un usuario con una reputación larga en el sitio (no vamos a dar el nombre para no avergonzarlo), dió una respuesta que creía válida, incluso asegura que llegó (según me dicen) a validarla en un fiddle. No sé que que le debe haber ocurrido a este señor, por que él sabe perfectamente que mezclar `dates` con `datetimes` es mal negocio.

> Lo increíble de esto, es que cosechó en pocos minutos una cantidad
>   importante de votos, 5, en una respuesta que estaba técnicamente
>   mal !!.

Luego @Aprendiz (Gracias!) de manera amable y hasta diría tímida, le hace una acertada observación a este señor, quién rápidamente comprende el grueso error cometido y corrige su publicación para que cumpla efectivamente con lo que se pedía.

Lecciones aprendidas:

- Por mi parte, ser más escéptico conmigo mismo.
- Nadie es inmune a equivocarse
- Por el lado de la comunidad, pareciera que la reputación pesa mucho a la hora de evaluar un contenido

Todo esto viene a colación de [¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Vox Populi?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4188/ya-conseguiste-tu-medalla-vox-populi) dónde se busca incentivar la participación mediante el voto. La pregunta entonces sería: ¿Que podemos hacer para minimizar este comportamiento? ¿Se puede hacer algo?

Comment: Exactamente, lo mismo pasa con los votos por *colegueo* (aunque no tan frequentemente) los cuales se controlan por el sitio y los puedes detectar por las grandes bajadas de puntuacion de users al cabo de un tiempo. [Votación corregida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: Estoy muy de acuerdo. Hace poco vi el caso de una respuesta incorrecta que en pocos momentos recibió 3 votos positivos (en estos momentos aún tiene dos). El problema es que en el futuro algún usuario al ver que tiene votos positivos la usará y se dará de bruces con el error.

Comment: Y quizas un efecto similar es cuando se trata de *compensar* los votos negativos con votos positivos.

Comment: Relacionado: [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83)

Comment: ¿Qué se puede hacer? No tenernos tan mal acostumbrados a responder tan bien las preguntas de SQL ;-) Fuera coñas, creo que es importante votar después de validar si lo que se dice tiene sentido. Votar "porque parece que está bien" es un mal servicio para el sitio.

Comment: ¿Qué hay en el caso de una respuesta bastante extensa, con investigación profunda y fuentes confiables, pero que no solucione la pregunta? Estos votos positivos ¿se verían como un premio al mérito o al esfuerzo?

Comment: @JheymanMejia, pero en tu ejemplo, se estaría votando el contenido y no la reputación. Lo cierto, es que hay absoluta libertad para votar como se quiera, la idea de este pregunta, es plantear que la reputación no es necesariamente garantía de una buena respuesta. Podemos seguir votando por reputación, pero no lo hagamos asumiendo que estamos votando por el contenido.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SIIIIII

exactamente lo que decís. No votar solo por la reputación, si no validar el contenido de la misma.

Creo que soy uno de los primeros en siempre criticar una respuesta para que quede correcta antes de darle mi voto positivo, sabiendo que la respuesta esta a centímetros de estar correcta o ser "perfecta".

Con gusto hemos tenido discusiones sobre preguntas, respuestas, y hemos llegado a acuerdos sobre las mismas. Estamos en un momento donde el caudal de votos es bajo y perjudica. Sin embargo, aquellos que ya tienen una buena reputación en el sitio no son inmunes a cometer errores o dejar lagunas en sus respuestas.

Votar solo por la reputación, sin tener en cuenta los datos que la misma contiene, es también un problema.

Debemos encarar los dos temas al mismo tiempo. Usuarios con experiencia (no solo en el sitio, no hablo de reputación), deben validar las respuestas antes de decir si corresponde darle un empujón a la misma. También deben criticar (positivamente) para llegar a dar una respuesta todavía mejor y mas correcta, inclusive aportando en la misma con ediciones (a mi me encanta que alguien corrija mis publicaciones agregándoles valor).

Aprendamos a criticar positivamente todo lo que pasa en el sitio. Inclusive a criticar actitudes de usuarios, para que los mismos comprendan que si todos empujamos para adelante, el sitio sera todavía mas receptivo y tendrá una participación mucho mas activa.

Comment: quizas sea mejor decir *No votar por la reputación, si no validar el contenido de la misma*, nadie deberia votar la reputación :-)

Answer (score 5):

Me sucedió en una ocasión, incluso mi respuesta había sido aceptada. Cuando me di cuenta que otro usuario tenía la respuesta correcta, voté por su respuesta y añadí en un comentario al OP que mi respuesta no era correcta para que me quitara la respuesta aceptada.

El problema creo, no es tanto si te equivocas, porque puedes editar la respuesta, corregirla y aclarar que te equivocaste. En este caso ya tienes cinco votos y difícilmente veo que te quiten votos o le sumen votos a @Aprendiz. Entonces lo mejor es corregirla para que futuros usuarios no tomen como válida una respuesta con error. En el caso de @Aprendiz, aunque esos votos deberían ser para él, creo que su propósito ya fue cumplido, el haber ayudado de mejor manera al usuario.

El problema creo que va en el sentido de equivocarse y no darse cuenta (o incluso darse cuenta y no editar la respuesta por no reconocerlo, lo que sería peor). En ese caso, lo que nos queda a los demás antes de votar es **cuestionar, cuestionar y cuestionar**. En algunas ocasiones me han cuestionado respuestas y al responderlas, he visto que aprendemos ambos. Y claro, una cosa muy diferente es cuestionar, como hizo @Aprendiz, y otra atacar como he visto en algunas ocasiones.

Answer (score 3):

Es un tema complicado: por un lado la reputación la has ganado aportando muchas veces en el sitio, con lo que es normal que el resto de usuarios te pueda ver como alguien a quien hacer caso (una *autoridad en la materia*).

Por otro lado, todos nos equivocamos, entendemos mal una pregunta o asumimos cosas incorrectamente al responder. Además, revisar el código de otras respuestas y comprobar que solucionan el problema a menudo es trabajoso, y se deja la tarea al OP.

Es verdad que recibo más votos de lo que a veces pienso que debería recibir, incluso cuando la respuesta es incorrecta he recibido votos a favor. Lo importante para mí en esas situación es saber reaccionar y arreglar el desaguisado cuanto antes y advertir al OP o quien haya visto tu código de que revise tu última edición o use otra respuesta como solución.

Eso e intentar ganar la medalla de [espíritu deportivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship), votando a otras respuestas: esto no es una competición; la "ludificación" de SE en general debería asumirse como un juego en modo "cooperativo".

Comment: @PrettyAvocado Sería lo ideal, pero sólo sabiendo la cantidad de veces que toman el código de tu respuesta y la copian tal cual, pierdes la esperanza de que eso sea la norma.