# ¿Es válido donar una buena cantidad de puntos por medio de recompensas a otro usuario?

Tags: discusión, reputación, recompensas

No encontré una pregunta similar, por lo cual la formulo.

En los últimos días, he visto que el usuario Paul Vargas ha dado dos recompensas amplias (de 500 puntos cada una), y próximamente creería que va a otorgar otra de 350 puntos al mismo usuario: [Pedro Miguel Pimienta Morales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2896/pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales?tab=profile). Si bien sus respuestas pueden ser útiles, no me parecen respuestas excepcionales, como para una recompensa tan «alta» (de hecho una de esas respuestas me pareció mediocre).

Las tres preguntas a las que me refiero son las siguientes:

- [¿Cómo obtener el width?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91130/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-width/91205#91205)
- [Limitar el tamaño de un informe en access al momento de imprimir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54341/limitar-el-tama%c3%b1o-de-un-informe-en-access-al-momento-de-imprimir/55697#55697)
- [Comprobar input vacio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16436/comprobar-input-vacio)

No tengo ningún problema en que el usuario Paul Vargas regale todos sus puntos, pero me surgió la curiosidad si este tipo de comportamientos son «válidos» en la comunidad.

Comment: Paul ya tiene un pasado de "suicidio de reputacion". Hacia 2018 pasó de 4k a pocos cientos en unos dias: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML4Pj.png . Es una actitud altruista quizá, pero está perdiendo privilegios que ayudarían a la comunidad más que los puntos en sí. Creo que de hacerlo, las recompensas deberian ser menos cuantiosas y más repartidas... pero cada uno hace lo que quiere con sus puntos.

Comment: @lois6b y la perdió de la misma manera, solo ofreciendo recompensas https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ecDx.png en total como se puede apreciar, ha dado más de 6000 puntos en recompensas

Comment: Técnicamente el concepto de "donar reputación" no existe en SE, lo que existe son "recompensas". Si bien cada usuario puede otorgar las recompensas que desee a quien lo desee está prohibido "vender" la reputación y hacer "mal uso" de las recompensas. No estoy seguro que el caso particular que comentas se considere "mal uso".

Comment: Creo que esto es equivalente al [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83). Debemos recompensar por contenido, no por personas. Se da reputación a una publicación, no a una persona. Si estamos muy contentos con una serie de publicaciones de alguien, votémoslas, mejorémoslas, démosles recompensas, amámoslas... pero lo que es engañar al sistema es pasar a adorar automáticamente a esa persona o darle puntos por publicaciones que no lo valen

Comment: ¿Hay algo que evite que dos usuarios (que podrían ser la misma persona) se estén recompensando de forma infinita las preguntas del uno y del otro y así promocionando sus preguntas infinitamente en la sección de recompensas? ¿Debería haber algún tipo de "impuesto" por dar recompensas? Por ejemplo si quisiera dar una recompensa de 100 puntos, ¿debería costarme 110 puntos?

Comment: @ordago para que eso ocurriera uno debería ser el autor de la pregunta y otro el autor de una de las respuestas. Sería raro y sospechoso, ciertamente, pues indicaría que la respuesta no está respondiendo.

Comment: Al ya pasar una semana me pregunto ¿Qué se decidio? Ademas me gustaria conocer la opinión de los moderadores diamantados sobre el tema ya que son los unicos que pueden intervenir ya que tienen los poderes necesarios para revertir las acciones si es necesario.

Answer (score 11):

No es válido porque las recompensas tienen un propósito si no se usan así, se está haciendo mal uso de ellas y esto debería reportarse.

---

En un comentario a la  pregunta mencioné lo siguiente

> Técnicamente el concepto de "donar reputación" no existe en SE, lo que existe son "recompensas". Si bien cada usuario puede otorgar las recompensas que desee a quien lo desee está prohibido "vender" la reputación y hacer "mal uso" de las recompensas. No estoy seguro que el caso particular que comentas se considere "mal uso"

Aprovecho esta publicación para precisar que el asignar una recompensa a un miembro de la comunidad no se realiza de forma directa sino a través de una respuesta porque lo que se recompensa es el valor dado a la comunidad a través de las respuestas, ni por simpatía, ni por participar en el chat ni por participar en Meta, ni siquiera por publicar buenas preguntas.

Relacionado Meta SE

- [Am I allowed to bounty for other reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143473/289691)

Relacionado

- [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/65)
- [No votemos positivamente por la reputación, votemos el contenido!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4192/65)

Comment: Concuerdo con lo que señalas, entonces supongo que el paso siguiente es que un moderador diamantado tome cartas en el asunto.(+1 por el enlace que estuve buscando ya que suponia que no es la primera vez que sucede este tipo de casos)

Answer (score 10):

Como comenté en el comentario bajo la pregunta, a la hora de dar recompensas yo pienso que de hacer como Paul hace, es mejor dar menos cantidad y más repartidas (a diversos usuarios, etiquetas, ...)

Tenía curiosidad por la respuesta que se iba a llevar la ultima pregunta citada por Shaz y pregunté a Paul en el chat: *"¿va a ser una de las respuestas ya dadas o una respuesta futura motivada por la recompensa"?*.

La respuesta de Paul me dejó de piedra ya que al parecer, [*"En realidad tampoco la pregunta es importante. La seleccioné al azar de las respuestas que ha dado un usuario en particular."*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53393667#53393667), [*"la recompensa se dará al usuario que yo ya elegí"*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53393760#53393760).

Cuando yo comentaba que cada uno hace lo que quiere con sus puntos, obviamente es dentro de lo razonable en el sistema.

Las recompensas están pensadas para que alguien que no recibió suficientes votos por una respuesta de gran calibre tenga un boost extra en reputacion; que al final es el medidor de cuán bueno es o lo mucho que se esfuerza en ayudar, buscar informacion y resolver problemas de los demás.

Tras las duras declaraciones de Paul, opino que no **debería** ser válidas esas "donaciones" ya que rompe la idea de recompensar.

Por ejemplo, la ultima pregunta, la respuesta de Pedro ni siquiera tiene explicación. Sólo código. Algo que no se acepta ya que lo importante es enseñar el error y no dar la solución en bandeja.

Comment: Lo siento mucho, pero tengo que votar negativo a pesar de estar de acuerdo en cuanto a la ética de la cuestión. En ningún sitio se especifica que recompensar a un usuario en cuestión todos los puntos que uno quiera sea malo, independientemente de la calidad de sus respuestas, esté prohibido.

Comment: @DavidDPG Gracias por comentar el motivo del negativo. Aunque no esté escrito, quizá deberia. hay muchas cosas que se "escriben" sobre la marcha en cuanto a como queremos que algo funcione o sea. Por que algo haya sido asi durante mucho tiempo no significa que sea inmutablde. Y lo puro de las recompensas es recompensar. Si ese usuario se lo merece, otorgalo donde así sea y no eligiendo al azar. Y si no lo merece, las recompensas desvirtuan el sitio.

Comment: Concuerdo. Quizá deberíamos abrir otra pregunta en meta que sirva de votación acerca de si esta actitud está mal vista en la comunidad, pero repito que no creo que se vayan a establecer mecanismos para evitarlo, y lo único que podremos hacer al respecto es comentarlo.

Comment: Buen día, Agustín Omaña, relativamente nuevo aquí, @DavidDPG en este caso voy más con **lois6b**, se está llenando el sitio de preguntas que desvían deliveradamente la atención a los verdaderos problemas, y la gente aquí invierte su tiempo en una competencia vacía, yo caí en la publicación por accidente y me llamó la atención la cantidad tan elevada de recompensa, y el interés desmedido en contestarla, es totalmente absurdo el comportamiento y falto de ética moral, se está cayendo en la "diversión" de un usuario el con "poder"

Comment: @DavidDPG Hay acciones no reglamentadas explicitamente ya que cuando se planearon nadie previo acciones que abusen del sistema, y entonces se discutieron haciendo reglas explicitas como pretendemos ahora. Por otro lado aunque no haya regla explicita los moderadores diamantados tienen más libertad en manejar estos casos pudiendo revertir los puntos y sancionar si es necesario.

Answer (score 5):

El tema de la reputación es meramente subjetivo, mientras que para algunos es un motivador para seguir contribuyendo en el sitio, para otros podría ser absolutamente nada.

Concuerdo con el comentario de @Rubén, mientras que el término "donar reputación" no exista, sería meramente incorrecto tratar de darle ese enfoque.

En el 2018 el señor @PaulVargas sufrió una suspensión de 7 días por las mismas acciones de dar recompensas a diestra y siniestra, y hasta donde recuerdo la justificación fue un intento de bandalismo ya que se pudo haber prestado a un hackeo o suplantación de identidad y en casos particulares y eventuales como este, creo que lo ideal sería que un moderador se pusiera en contacto con Paul para corroborar y confirmar que realmente es él, y en el caso que así sea, dejar que haga lo que desee con su reputación.

Mi punto es, no es bueno ni malo, ni válido ni inválido, cada quien le puede poner la etiqueta que desee, a menos que llegue alguna nueva política por parte de SO que impida este comportamiento y nos corran a todos.

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta, pero no he leido en el sitio algo como  _"donar reputación"_ si es asi debemos de mejorar esa traduccion, incluso sacarla de nuestro vocabulario a la hora del moderar

Comment: @JackNavaRow no existe "donar reputación", por eso digo en la respuesta que no es correcto usar ese término

Answer (score -2):

En las [FAQ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) no aparece nada acerca de la validez o ética acerca de las recompensas, únicamente se explica cómo asignarlas y las limitaciones que tiene el sistema. En caso de que penalizase la "recompensa serial", al igual que los votos seriales, sería explícito en esa página.

De hecho tomando en cuenta [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/622229) (en inglés) las recompensas son la alternativa válida al voto serial positivo.

Lo cual me lleva a pensar que las recompensas pueden ser usadas de forma subjetiva por cualquier usuario, ya sea para encontrar una respuesta mejor a una dada, para animar a la comunidad a dar respuestas a una pregunta que no tenga, o para recompensar una excelente respuesta.

Si tomamos en cuenta la subjetividad que ya he establecido antes, a este usuario podría haberle parecido que las respuestas que comentas son excepcionales, aunque otros usuarios puedan discrepar.

Comment: Y supongo que se admite como *alternativa válida al voto serial positivo* porque está limitada: cada punto que das, lo pierdes tú.

Comment: @PabloLozano Ahora que dices eso, imagino que es análogo al dinero: una cosa es generarlo ilegalmente y otra muy distinta es gastarlo en las cosas que tú quieras

Answer (score -3):

Los puntos son inequiparables, de lo que se trata es de aportar experiencia, conocimiento y hacerlo trascender.

Muy cercano al dilema moral, hay gente aquí que ha trabajado por mejorar la calidad del sitio y no necesitó ninguna puntuación especial para brindar el apoyo.

Estamos por el gusto de ayudar, que sea esa nuestra recompensa.

Comment: Aún y cuando en Meta es válido dar puntos de vistas / respuestas basadas en opiniones la respuestas deben responder la pregunta. En este caso al menos las respuestas deberían ser acerca de la discrecionalidad de las recompensas y mejor aún si trataran sobre el uso reiterado de dicha discrecionalidad para beneficiar a un usuario (independientemente de quien se trate).

Comment: No es válido, ya lo he mencionado, son inequiparables, no se compara con una respuesta normal; lo que por otro lado es la función de **recompensa**, el hacerlo reiteradamente demerita la calidad del sitio (también lo menciono), sin embargo no hay nada que diga que no se puede hacer

Comment: Bueno los privilegios de moderación vienen con la reputación.