# ¿Queremos una pestaña "Sin respuestas" en la barra de navegación principal?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, interfaz-de-usuario

#### Actualización 21 mayo 2020

Esto se ha implementado y ya aparece la pestaña [Sin responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) en el sitio principal.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Muchas gracias a [@Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano) por la traducción.

---

La mayoría de las comunidades de Stack Exchange tiene la pestaña "Sin respuesta" en la barra de navegación principal. Por ejemplo, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

Parece que Stack Overflow en español no tiene esta pestaña. He hablado con mis colegas y no hay objeciones para añadirla.

¿Podríais comentar si queréis ver el enlace a preguntas sin respuesta en la barra de navegación principal? ¿Se os ocurren motivos por los que no deberíamos añadirlo?

---

Aclaración: Las preguntas consideradas sin respuesta son aquellas que no tienen una respuesta aceptada ni alguna con puntuación positiva.

Answer (score 8):

#### Yo creo que es una buena idea

Votamos poco, muy poco: [somos el 3.º por la cola de un total de 173 sitios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4189/83). Este es un problema grande.

Además, resulta que [somos el 4.º por la cola en tanto por ciento de preguntas con respuesta](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#percentanswered), con apenas el 62%. Como referencia, Stack Overflow está en el 70%, SOpt en el 75%, SOru en el 72% y SOja en el 78%. Además, aproximadamente la mitad de sitios de toda la red está por encima del 90%.

Lo preocupante es que cuando salimos de beta hace dos años este valor estaba en el 72% ([datos en Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)). Si por aquel entonces Area 51 nos indicaba que este valor *necesitaba trabajo*, ahora necesita aún más si queremos contar con un sitio sano y útil.

Con todos estos números quiero decir que la métrica de preguntas con respuesta es importante, se ha utilizado históricamente para marcar el nivel de salud del sitio y, si la aceptamos como tal, debemos tenerla en cuenta. Contar con este listado de preguntas de forma más accesible nos ayudará a cerrar las que no valgan la pena (y por tanto no computen en el algoritmo) y a intentar resolver las que sí estén bien.

Comment: Supongo que la consulta no considera preguntas eliminadas o en espera, pero parte de ese porcentaje en SOE es por la cantidad de preguntas de pobre calidad, mal redactadas, que pareciera que ni el mismo autor sabe lo que quiere y se quedan ahí por siempre sin ser respondidas.
En contraste con el sitio en inglés, en el que son extremadamente exigentes, incluso me han editado respuestas solo porque no fui más conciso expresándome. Gran parte de las preguntas que menciono al principio no duran mucho en ser puestas en espera o eliminadas, garantizando un porcentaje más alto de respuestas.

Comment: @aeportugal destacas con mucha precisión dos de los males de esta comunidad: hace falta más involucración en recepción de las preguntas nuevas, para que las malas se cierren rápido y las buenas emerjan bien. Votar y revisar, votar y revisar, votar y revisar.

Answer (score 7):

Quisiera señalar que ya existe una forma de obtener las preguntas que no tienen respuestas o tienen una respuesta sin votos. [Preguntas sin responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)

*I'd like to point out that there is already a tab in questions to filter unanswered questions*

[image: Filtros de preguntas]

Sin responder (Not answered)

Añadir un enlace directo no me parece especialmente útil (uso poco esa pestaña), pero tampoco es que tengamos tantas opciones en la barra de navegación como para que una más moleste.

I think there is no need to add a more direct link to it, but we only have 4 options in the main navigation, so another one won't harm (and other users could find it more useful)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con tu opinión. Yo personalmente tengo esa pestaña oculta, por lo que añadir enlaces ahi no me parece especialemente útil, pero como bien dices añadir una opción mas en dicho menú tampoco va a influir de forma negativa.

Comment: A mi también me parece innecesario añadir esa opción al menú. En caso de ponerla en la pantalla principal la pondría en el bloque de filtros, no en el menú.

Answer (score 2):

Como comento [Pablo Lozano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4340/28035) ya existe Preguntas sin Responder,

Sin embargo, Creo que podemos agregar algo como

> Mis preguntas sin aceptar

Donde este enlace se activara cuando el Usuario tenga por lo menos 1 Pregunta con esta característica. y así las estadísticas que menciona [fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4341/28035) podrían mejorar incentivando a los Usuarios a responder ,aceptar o eliminar sus preguntas

Comment: Cuando entras en tu propio perfil, sección preguntas, esto ya sale: te pone una pequeña frase del tipo _oye recuerda que esta pregunta no tiene respuesta aceptada_. Esto ocurre si tienes alguna respuesta (supongo que con votos positivos) y hasta que llegas a cierta reputación.

Comment: En las páginas en inglés dice _Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?_. No encuentro en Meta.SE explicación clara de cuándo sale, pero a mí me ha aparecido en distintos sitios.

Answer (score 0):

Yo quiero una pestaña "Sin respuestas por mí", aunque me conformaría con un filtro personalizado.

Hoy día es fácil buscar las preguntas sin respuestas, sólo basta escribir en la caja de búsqueda `isanswered:0`

Algo así ya ha sido sugerido en Meta SE, por ejemplo en [una de las respuestas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312788/289691) a [Custom question lists: finding questions you can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/289691)

Mi única objeción a tener la pestaña "Sin respuestas" sería que esta interfiera de cualquier modo con "Sin respuestas por mí"

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, sería útil