# ¿Cuándo las ediciones o correcciones a preguntas o comentarios pueden afectar a un usuario colaborador?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, votos, comentarios

En el poco tiempo que llevo en la plataforma he notado que para mejorar una pregunta o comentario se pueden hacer ediciones, o en los comentarios hacer referencia a el uso adecuado de la plataforma, la cuestión es la siguiente, y como experiencia personal, he visto que muchas personas requieran preguntas, comentarios o simplemente no siguen colaborando con las resoluciones de preguntas debido al **exceso de correcciones** digamos aperturas de signos de pregunta y exclamación, y te sugieren edición, si en algún comentario cometes errores ortográficos, algún otro miembro colaborador se toma la tarea de decirte **mira este enlace de cómo comentar** y está bien que te ayuden a entender cómo funciona la comunidad y la plataforma, pero esto conlleva a que las personas se **abstengan de preguntar o responder preguntas** porque las reciben con votos negativos y correcciones a veces un tanto innecesarias, creo que no solo pasa con los miembros nuevos de la comunidad sino también, con algunos que ya llevamos algún tiempo.

Por lo cual, si ponemos esta pregunta de ejemplo, no sé si será castigada, por que se asemeje o no a otra hecha en la comunidad, aunque desde mi criterio en preguntas similares no se parezca a otra, lo cual me lleva a pensar **¿qué tanto se debe corregir una pregunta o comentario hecho en la comunidad Meta o Normal?**

**Actualización**

Haciendo referencia a usuarios nuevos tanto meta como en la normal, si un usuario nuevo pregunta, como en mi caso con esta pregunta en meta, recibe puntos negativos claro que las razones pueden ser totalmente válidas para en punto en negativo, esto puede llevar a que un posible nuevo colaborador no use la plataforma, lo que me lleva a **cuestionar** la funcionalidad de la manita **Nuevo colaborador** y el mensaje **"Se amable con el nuevo colaborador"**.

Comment: Yo nunca he escuchado que alguien dé un downvote por mala ortografía. Las ediciones tienen como objetivo pulir la publicación para que sea de calidad ya que ese es el objetivo del sitio: Preguntas y respuestas de calidad. Por lo que en general no se debe justificar los votos pero se recomienda dar un upvote si la publicación es buena para el votante, y downvote si es mala. Asi que no hay una relación directa entre la ortografía y los votos.

Comment: Por otro lado siempre es recomendable es tener presión/compromiso cuando se hace una pregunta ya que implica pedir a los demás invertir un poco de su valioso tiempo para ayudarte, esa presión debe ser similar a la que se tiene cuando se entrega un trabajo a un profesor o jefe, ¿Tú entregarías un trabajo mal redactado a tu jefe o profesor?, pienso que no, pues lo mismo se aplica aca pero la gran diferencia es que nosotros te ayudamos ha mejorar las preguntas corrigiendo la redacción y ortografía de la publicación.

Comment: Yo pienso que estas asumiendo que los downvotes que reciben estan asociados a la redacción u ortografía, pero no, eso no es verdad. De mi experiencia en SO la mala redacción u ortografía no conlleva a downvotes, sino que en gran medida los downvotes son dados a las preguntas que no estan dentro de los lineamientos de SO como por ejemplo pedir opiniones, pedir que hagan su trabajo, preguntas demasiados amplias, etc.

Comment: Asi que mi respuesta a tu pregunta es: Tantas veces como sea necesaria para que la publicación sea de calidad, y si consideras que han hecho muchas ediciones en tus publicaciones entonces te recomiendo a tomarte más tiempo en la redacción, lo recomendable es media hora para proveer una pregunta de calidad, preguntarle a tus amigos si esta bien redactado, si la pregunta es clara, etc. En conclusión aqui intentaremos tener las publicaciones con la mayor calidad posible, ese es el plus de este sitio.

Comment: Nota: Los comentarios no son editables por otro usuarios y ademas que tienen un umbral de 5 minutos para la edición del propio usuario.

Comment: @eyllanesc comparto tu opinión sobre la falta de relación entre ortografía y votos negativos. Creo que deberías poner todos tus comentarios como respuesta.

Comment: El llenar de votos negativos [nosotros como comunidad también lo hemos planteado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4188/28035), y pues a los usuarios nuevos generalmente somos mas permisivos he intentamos que pregunten bien, si un usuario nuevo [hace una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/316511/28035) lo usuarios frecuente los premiamos! en caso de que haga una mala pregunta por lo general tratamos de llevarlo por buen camino y si no los usuarios frecuentes cerramos la pregunta evitando tantos -1

Comment: Respondiendo al título de tu pregunta: Cuando son destructivas o cuando son un intento de respuesta, en ambos casos, y por lo general, estas ediciones no son aprobadas o son revertidas. De resto, no tienen porqué afectar el normal funcionamiento de la plataforma. Te recomiendo visitar: [¿Por qué puede la gente editar mis mensajes? ¿Cómo funciona el trabajo de edición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: Digamos haciendo referencia a el caso de esta pregunta, como tal nunca había preguntado o participado en la comunidad meta, por lo cual tener 5 puntos en negativo aun usuario completamente nuevo, lo puede llevar que no participe nuevamente en la plataforma es decir se puede perder aun colaborador, es el punto a mi pregunta.

Comment: Los puntos en negativo dentro de Meta son solo señal de que varios usuarios no están de acuerdo con tu opinión pero hasta ahí. Por otro lado al menos a mi me parece que no quisieras recibir votos negativos, toda vez que estos indican por ejemplo en la comunidad que tal vez tu aporte no responde a las reglas de [ask] o de [answer], sin embargo siempre que mejoremos nuestros aportes esos negativos se van como positivos

Comment: Pero para no ser redundante, la respuesta de Pablo lo explica mejor

Comment: Los votos en meta no reflejan la calidad de la pregunta, si no que se usan para expresar si se esta en acuerdo o desacuerdo con lo propuesto. Tene en cuenta que los mismos en meta no suman ni restan, no valen nada. Asi que no te preocupes por los mismos, estan indicando que la gente no opina que pasa lo que vos propones.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Precisamente editamos las preguntas para evitar que sean ignoradas: una pregunta bien escrita, sin faltas de ortografía y semántica, con un escenario claro y acotado, atraerá más a los que tienen conocimientos sobre el tema tratado.

Además, muchas ediciones son hechas por usuarios que no pueden dar una respuesta pero quieren aportar a la calidad del sitio.

En lugar de molestarte por las ediciones a tus preguntas / respuestas, intenta lo opuesto: una pregunta (o respuesta) muy mala, que se considera *insalvable*, es votada negativo y/o marcada para cerrar. Si alguien se tomó la molestia de ayudar al OP haciendo correcciones en lugar de simplemente ignorarla o cerrarla, es porque la consideró digna de ese esfuerzo.

Hasta los mejores escritores de novelas tienen un editor que corrige erratas, pide cambios en el texto, sugiere mejoras... ¡y cobran por ello!

Comment: @OP, en mi experiencia, las ediciones que se han hecho a mis preguntas/respuestas siempre ha sido para mejorar la calidad. También han sido una forma de que te den un pequeño tirón de orejas para que a la próxima vez lo trates de hacer mejor y prestes más atención sin tener que avergonzarte con un comentario de "te has dejado una tilde" que no aporta a la discusión. Ayer, sin ir más lejos, el caballero que te acaba de responder editó una respuesta que escribí dejándola mejor, ya que encontró un fallo del que no me dí cuenta. En vez de una ida y venida de mensajes, simplemente lo arregló.