# ¿Por qué se usan tan poco los votos en la valoración de preguntas y respuestas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta, votos

Desconozco si la pregunta será bienvenida, o por el contrario, no pinte nada el hacerla, pero es algo que me llama poderosamente la atención.

Yo uso la comunidad como apoyo en mis estudios de informática, y tengo que decir, que en muchas ocasiones he podido resolver dudas que ni siquiera mis profesores eran capaces de despejar.

En la comunidad me encuentro con malas y muy malas preguntas, que la gente formula para que les hagan sus tareas. Sin embargo, me he encontrado muy buenas preguntas, y muy buenas e incluso excelentes respuestas. Pero, contrario a lo que sucede en la página inglesa, que he accedido en varias ocasiones, hay preguntas y respuestas con votos superiores a la treintena, aquí en la comunidad en español se ven muy pocos votos, tanto en preguntas como en respuestas.

La verdad es que solo he formulado un par de preguntas, pues comentaba, lo uso más para hojear respuestas y métodos de programación que sirvan para adquirir nuevos conocimientos, pero cada vez que entro, me gusta curiosear en las preguntas de los últimos días; y si las veo interesantes, otorgar mis votos, y me llama la atención lo que había escrito antes, la poca cantidad de votos que me encuentro en preguntas y respuestas.

Por eso me llama la atención, cuál es el motivo de que la gente no valore ni las preguntas ni las respuestas.

Gracias por leerme

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo, este tema se ha comentado aqui en meta en numerosas ocasiones. Lamentablemente, poco hay que se pueda hacer, cada uno es libre de votar o no votar. Por otro lado, hay que tener cuidado con las comparaciones con SO. Alli el numero de usuarios es exponencialmente superior, por lo que el numero de votos logicamente tambien. Habría que comparar el nº de votos por visita para tener una comparativa exacta.

Comment: No presto atención a los votos. Creo que están para dar la ilusión de ser tomados en cuenta, cuando en realidad tu votación no cambia nada. Son acciones sin resultado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, la cultura del voto es pobre, ya que hay muchos usuarios que su interes es solamente resolver su problema e incluso despues de recibir una respuesta borran su publicacion(algo q molesta mucho, ya que es tu tiempo)

Comment: Se me ocurre que la carencia de votos sea debido a que las preguntas se van perdiendo con las nuevas. También, además de que hay muchísima menos gente que en SO, puede que allí tengan otra mentalidad, otra educación. Latinoamérica no está en sus mejores momentos.

Comment: SO tiene similar comportamiento a SOE. Las preguntas con cientos de votos ya tienen varios años de antigüedad (algunas hasta más de una década) y han venido recogiendo votos por mucho tiempo. Si visitan el home de SO, verán que más del 90% de las preguntas tienen 0 votos.

Comment: A veces te responden sin votar, otras votan sin responder... Por cierto, hay un bug, que si recibe un voto negativo luego no te notifican los positivos hasta que se toque la copa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Los Datos

Si bien es cierto que ninguna pregunta en SOes llega a las decenas de miles de votos, nuesta comunidad es minúscula en comparación con SO. Me parece que una aproximación más acertada es comparar el ratio *voto/ vista*.

Inspirado por tu pregunta, he echado un ojo en SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) para buscar alguna [query que permita calcular la media de este ratio](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=average%20votes%20per%20view), y me he topado con ésta, que [calcula la media y su desviación estándar](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/648699/average-votes-per-view-for-questions):

```
select avg(value), stdevp(value)
from (
select cast(count(v.Id) as float) / p.ViewCount as value
from Votes v, Posts p
where v.VoteTypeId in (2, 3)
and p.Id = v.PostId
and p.posttypeid = 1
group by p.ViewCount, p.id
) t
```

Lanzada sobre el dominio de Stackoverflow, da un valor de 0.011074 con desviación estándar 0.01835.

Lanzada sobre el dominio de Stackoverflow en español, da un valor de 0.017654 con desviación estándar 0.022477 **

Una grata sorpresa, parece que, en general, en nuestra comunidad los usuarios votan más que en StackOverflow en inglés, por visita. Esto me lleva a pensar que hay menos usuarios, pero que los que hay suelen estar más implicados con la filosofía del sitio.
La desviación estándar también es reseñable; es algo más alta que en el sitio en inglés, lo que me hace pensar que o bien somos más "desordenados", o bien tendemos a votar más las preguntas activas y que ya tienen algún voto y a dejar solas las preguntas que no han llegado a tener actividad.

En todo caso no soy estadístico, por lo que tanto el tratamiento de datos como la interpretación están sujetas a debate.

### Mi opinión

Por supuesto cada persona es diferente y nos motivan diferentes cosas. Comprendo perfectamente que alguien quiera ser el Jon Skeet de StackOverflow en español, y el sitio se presta a ello con el sistema de puntos.

La mayoría de las personas, sin embargo, no tiene por qué prestarse a seguir esta gamificación (sí, gamificación, recordemos que el sistema de puntos es algo opcional). Y si no quieres interactuar con estas personas, también estás en tu derecho, simplemente no les prestes atención y dedícate a lo que te guste más de este sitio, buscando información, haciendo preguntas interesantes y en general contribuyendo a hacer de este sitio un buen archivo de información colaborativa.

** He asumido que los esquemas son equivalentes, por lo que si no lo son estos datos no son válidos.

Comment: No creo que comparar votos por visitas sea la mejor métrica. En [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4189/83) voy actualizando los datos de votos por comunidades con las métricas que suelen mirarse más y en ella [es.so] es la penúltima (¡174 de 175!) en casi todas.

Comment: Si se cerrara más, probablemente la métrica mejoraría. También ayudaría marcar más duplicados, para que quien llegara desde Google se encontrara con algo muy útil y no volviera atrás en busca de otras páginas. Actualmente Google no nos tiene demasiado bien posicionados y hay cosas que están en nuestra mano.

Comment: En definitiva, interesante análisis pero creo que no pone luz sobre los elementos a mi parecer más relevantes. Si el sitio mejorara su SEO, entraría más gente y habría más votos, así como publicaciones de calidad. Luego habría que trabajar en hacer que se quieran quedar...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', el usuario que mas votos tiene en SOes tiene alrededor de 95K, y el que le sigue 75K. Quitando de este analisis a la comunidad inglesa, he visto que en la comunidad rusa y portuguesa(no se la japonesa) las primeras posiciones tienen digamos mas de 300K, en mi opinion a la comunidad espannola le falta cultura del voto. Eso sin entrar en otros analisis mas complejos desde el pto de vista social, por ejemplo America Latina gradua mas Licenciados en Ciencias Sociales que Ingenieros o Carreras de caracter tecnico, en Europa y America del Norte es al reves

Comment: Muchas gracias a tod@s por vuestras respuestas, me ha parecido un tema interesante de debate. Besinos

Answer (score 3):

**Introducción**
No estoy seguro de que esta respuesta sea de "teoría de juegos" pero daré la interpretación subjetiva que tengo al aplicarla a esta pregunta.

**Justificación**
Creo que invidivualmente hablando podemos justificar nuestras decisiones con el "libre albedrío" pero esta aproximación limitaría el estudio de las decisiones que toman los agentes en un sistema, en este caso el sistema de votación de overflow en español. Por lo que trataré de asumir que todos los usuarios con capacidad de votar son racionales y buscan maximizar su bienestar y minimizar su malestar:

**Hipotesis de equilibrio de Nash**

- Equilibrio actual: El equilibrio vendría siendo el ratio de votación
  bajo.
- Equilibrio deseado: Alto ratio de votación

Si asumimos que este sistema es un juego, cada
agente votaría si esta fuese la mejor opción conociendo todo lo que
sucedería luego de votar o no (por ejemplo si por cada voto dado recibiese un boleto de lotería (refuerzo positivo) o si cada voto que das te costase un punto de los que tienes (refuerzo negativo)).

**Análisis**
Al ver una buena respuesta o una buena pregunta, tienes dos opciones das tu voto o no lo das. al dar tu votos estas siendo altruista pues no estás recibiendo nada a cambio (tal vez los pocos votos que ves son el porcentaje de altruismo en la población), si no das tu voto no ganas nada ni pierdes nada. La mejor decisión (para una población racional sin altruismo) sería entonces la indiferencia (ya que ninguna es mejor que la otra) pero si somos indiferentes por qué no damos el voto? porque por defecto el voto no es dado... por ejemplo si apenas entrases a la respuesta y automáticamente se diera un voto la indeferencia te llevaría a no quitarlo.

**Conclusión**
Por lo que la baja votación debería estar relacionada por una falta de insentivos en los agentes... Usualmente hay un insentivos de "reconocimiento colectivo" (ver como referencia pirámide de maslow 4to peldaño) en conseguir votos, pero no hay insentivos en dar votos.

**Contrapunto** Insentivar el dar votos puede ser contraproducente ya que el que da votos no está haciendo un esfuerzo significativo y tampoco está tomando riesgos. Por lo que si das insentivos de esta forma probablemente las personas terminarían dando votos a favor a cualquier respuesta incluso si no son buenas Ya que la decisión más inteligente es que si tienes para ganar pero nada que perder pues darían votos a ciegas.

Para dar una solución práctica y real, pensaría que habría que hacer una encuesta. En particular conocer que insentiva a las personas que votan, y qué nuevo insentivo atraería a los que no lo hacen. El objetivo sería que la mejor decisión racional fuese dar votos a las buenas respuestas cuando las vez y evitar la indiferencia a la hora de dar votos a causa de la falta de insentivos.

***Nota:** no hay rigor científico, solo apelo al sentido común y al razonamiento.*

Answer (score 3):

Me gustaría añadir un matiz a algunas cosas que ha respondido [David DPG](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5186/2742):

> nuesta comunidad es minúscula en comparación con SO[en]

En poblaciones pequeñas, los efectos pequeños tienen más peso... y eso es importante por otra de las cosas que menciona:

> parece que, en general, en nuestra comunidad los usuarios votan más que en StackOverflow en inglés, por visita

Ahora voy a ir al terreno personal: mi usuario de SOes tiene cinco años y medio, he causado un impacto de ~1.5m, estoy en el 0.31% superior general y ahora mismo estoy en el puesto 9 del ránking total de SOes.

Aún siendo tan activo en la página he emitido sólo 1713 votos (0,8 votos al día). Te aseguro que la mayoría de esos 1700 votos han sido emitidos en mis tres primeros años en SOes, a día de hoy apenas voto.

Mi apatía hacia los votos está motivada por un cambio que nadie pidió: Hace un tiempo votar una pregunta otorgaba 5 puntos y votar una respuesta otorgaba 10; esto se cambió para que preguntas y respuestas tuvieran el mismo valor (10 puntos ambas). En mi opinión no tiene el mismo valor pedir ayuda que ofrecerla, no tiene el mismo valor buscar conocimiento que tenerlo y no tiene el mismo valor recibir que dar.

Mi reacción a dicho cambio fue dejar de votar, la pregunta o respuesta tiene que ser muy buena (o tiene que pertenecer a un usuario que respete mucho, normalmente ambas cosas) para que siquiera me plantee la posibilidad de valorar votar.

Yo soy sólo un usuario de los miles que tiene SOes, pero si otros usuarios veteranos con un posicionamiento importante en la página han tomado decisiones parecidas a la mía, podría explicar parte del comportamiento que has observado porque como he dicho: "En poblaciones pequeñas, los efectos pequeños tienen más peso".

Answer (score 1):

A parte de que la cultura del voto es pobre en la comunidad, ya que muchos solo vienen aquí a resolver un problema y después si te he visto ni me acuerdo, también hay otro elemento a tener en cuenta, la gente vota por lo que entiende, por ejemplo un algoritmo para calcular el area de un cuadrado, va ser entendido por mas miembros de la comunidad que uno para recorrer grafos, por tanto el algoritmo del calculo del area del cuadrado recibirá muchos mas votos que el algoritmo para recorrer grafos, ya que es entendido por muchas mas personas, a pesar de que hacer un algoritmo para recorrer grafos es mas interesante, retador y lleva mas esfuerzo.