# Menu para preguntas sin responder

Tags: característica-nueva, barra-de-navegación

## Contexto: quiero buscar preguntas sin responder fácilmente.

Estaba leyendo las preguntas sin responder y vi que había muchas, varias realizadas hace mucho tiempo y con muy pocas vistas (aparentemente pasaron sin que nadie les preste atención). Se puede ver desde la barra de navegación principal.

[image: Selector en la parte superior para preguntas Sin Responder]

---

## No entiendo para qué está la pestaña "*no hay respuestas*".

Ahora me pregunto por qué existe la opción <kbd>Sin responder</kbd>, cuando dentro de esta opción, en la barra de navegación se puede seleccionar <kbd>no hay respuesta</kbd>.

[image: Sin responder -> no hay respuesta]

Me parece que esto es algo confuso, o por lo menos a mí me lo parece, que si se cuenta con <kbd>Sin responder</kbd>, además exista <kbd>Sin responder</kbd> → <kbd>no hay respuesta</kbd>.

---

## No es fácil encontrar las últimas preguntas por fecha.

Se puede ir navegando con el paginado, pero es poco práctico en mi opinión. Además, si se va a la última página, salen las últimas dependiente del filtro que SO use para ello, con lo que te encuentras preguntas con votos negativos, así que no se puede ver fácilmente las últimas preguntas publicadas sin respuesta.

---

## Propuesta para agregar filtros de fecha.

¿No sería más útil poner una especie de menú para filtrar las preguntas por fecha? Algo así como un campo para poner las fechas:

```
 01/01/01 - 01/01/02
```

y unos checks por si no se quiere especificar unas fechas. Algo como esto:

```
* del día
* de la semana
* del mes
```

Podría ir dentro del recuadro de la imagen o en otro lugar mejor, sólo es orientativo.

[image: Propuesta para filtro de fecha]

Pienso que ayudaría a los usuarios que no han estado presentes mientras la cola de preguntas crecía, para que puedan ver mas fácil las preguntas sin respuesta, independientemente de los votos sólo dependiente del tiempo desde su publicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Qué es "Sin Responder"

En todo Stack Exchange, una pregunta fue **"respondida"** cuando:

- Tiene una respuesta aceptada, o
- Tiene una respuesta con puntaje total >= 1, o
- Fue cerrada.

<sup>* Definición de "respondida" según Jeff Atwood: [*OK, Now Define “Answered*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/).</sup>

Por ende, una pregunta está **"sin responder"** cuando está abierta, no tiene respuestas o, si tiene respuestas, ninguna fue aceptada y ninguna tiene un puntaje positivo.

En el sitio, está redactado como:

[image: preguntas que no tienen votos a favor ni respuestas aceptadas]

> preguntas que no tienen votos a favor ni respuestas aceptadas

(-bueno, podría estar un poquitín mejor)

**¿Y "no hay respuestas"?**

[image: Pestaña "no hay respuestas"]

Como vimos, dentro de "sin responder" se incluyen preguntas con respuestas no aceptadas y sin puntaje positivo. La pestaña **no hay respuestas** filtra aún más, mostrando sólo aquellas preguntas que no tengan ninguna respuesta.

Esta pestaña está presente dentro de la opción "Sin responder", así como también al filtrar por una(s) etiqueta(s).

**¿Y si quiero filtrar más aún?**

Para realizar búsquedas avanzadas, se pueden utilizar más parámetros.

Por ejemplo:

- `is:question closed:no answers:0 created:6d..`
  Preguntas no cerradas, sin respuestas, creadas en la última semana.
- `is:question hasaccepted:no lastactive:1d`
  Preguntas que no tienen respuestas aceptadas, que estuvieron activas entre ayer y hoy.
- `isanswered:no score:1 created:2016-11..2017-04-07`
  Preguntas sin responder, con puntaje >=1, creadas entre el 1/11/2016 y el 7/4/2017.

Para más parámetros, ver: [¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

---

### Nuevos filtros

Con respecto a agregar un nuevo checkbox o combo, no creo que sea bueno distanciarnos de la interfaz utilizada en todo Stack Exchange. Personalmente, las veces que entré al sitio japonés o al ruso, te aseguro que fue un gran beneficio tener todos los botones en el mismo lugar, y los mismos parámetros de búsqueda.

En todo caso, lo que sí me encantaría tener, al igual que muchos otros sitios de la red que piden lo mismo, son las pestañas personalizables de SOen:

[image: Pestaña personalizable de Stack Overflow]

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta *...personalizables de SOen:...* deje un post de que me gustaba la nueva nav de SOen, pero no conocia la parte que menciona,"hace tiempo que no uso SOen como antes".Saludos

Comment: que cosas he estado por SOen por familiarizarme con la nueva nav y he visto que cambiaron lo que comente en mi ultimo update que decia que me parecia confuso que existiera, ahora en SOen cuando vas a `Preguntas -> sin responder` te redirecciona a `Sin responder -> no hay respuesta` como dije en un post yo quiero esa nav +1 al equipo de diseño. Saludos

Comment: Creo que en el menú de arriba, en lugar de _Sin responder_, debería decir: __*Sin atender*__. En la definición del Merrian-Webster (la 3) _"Answer"_ se define como _hacer algo en respuesta o reacción_. En la RAE, _"atender"_, la definición 4 dice: _"Tener en cuenta o en consideración algo"_. En el diccionario básico escolar Norma ed. 2011, _"atender"_ se define como _aplicar la mente o los sentidos al conocimiento de algo_. Esas preguntas requieren algún tipo de atención (una respuesta, un voto, un reporte), __lo que sea, pero *deben ser atendidas*__.

Comment: @toledano Interesante punto de vista, más teniendo en cuenta que esto es algo que causa confusión frecuentemente, tanto en español como en inglés. Sin embargo "sin responder", "respondidas", o "porcentaje de respondidas" son términos que **se utilizan en todo el sitio** (e incluso como "*answered*" en SOen). Ejemplo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1279/127 ... Un cambio así debería ser propuesto por separado, aunque tendría la contra de estar separándose de los términos utilizados en todo SE.