# Pongamosle atención a las preguntas con más de 1000 vistas que no han recibido atención por los moderadores

Tags: discusión, votos

Resumen:

Como menciono en el título pongamosle atención a las preguntas con más de 1000 vistas que "no han sido atendidas por los moderadores", es decir, por quienes tenemos los privilegios para votar.

Preguntas únicamente que no tienen respuesta aceptada con un puntaje de 0 y un número de vistas mayor a 1000 y que están abiertas

[questions only no accepted answer not closed score 0 views>= 1000](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+votes%3A0..0+views%3A1000+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3A0)

<s>[questions only no accepted answer score 0 views>= 1000](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+votes%3A0..0+views%3A1000+hasaccepted%3A0)</s>

---

Si el número de vistas no te convence, ¿que tal las preguntas antiguas que tienen una puntuación de 0 y ninguna respuesta? Por ejemplo, tenemos casi 5k  preguntas que tienen más de un año en esta situación:

[Preguntas abiertas con puntuación menor igual a 0 creadas antes del 2018-06 con 0 respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A..2018-06+answers%3A0+votes%3A...0+is%3Aq+closed%3A0)

---

> A lo mejor las preguntas si fueron atendidas en su momento al pasar por las colas de revisión, por el momento no considero muy útil profundizar mucho, en lo que quiero hacer énfasis es que votemos las preguntas que de una u otra forma están siendo vistas y que tienen una puntuación de 0 y que no tienen respuesta aceptada.

Al visitar la página principal del sitio me llamó la atención una pregunta con varias respuestas y mas de mil vistas. Al verla con mayor detalle me sorprendió que la pregunta fue relanzada por Comunidad, que la pregunta y ninguna de sus respuestas tiene votos, ni positivos ni negativos, tampoco ningún comentario.

Al verla con mayor detalle me pareció que la pregunta no es una buena pregunta, las respuestas no son extraordinarias y recordé la sugerencia de un experto en otro sitio de que este tipo de preguntas no vale la pena votarlas para cerrar ya que con un voto negativo serán eliminadas, así que voté negativamente.

Luego se me ocurrió buscar preguntas en una situación similar y encontré que tenemos <s>478</s> **440** en esta situación, me pareció que son muchas y que seguramente las vistas son de usuarios que no tienen los privilegios para votar. Me parece que ayudaremos al sitio a mejorar la impresión que damos a los visitantes esporádicos si las preguntas que encuentran tienen votos.

Ejerzamos nuestro privilegio de voto.

Si es una buena métrica discutámoslo en los hilos sobre métricas. Abajo se incluyen algunos enlaces.

Relacionado (mas antiguos primero)

- [¿Cuándo debería votar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1075/65)
- [Métricas interesantes para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1998/65)
- [Midamos los esfuerzos de la comunidad usando métricas específicas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4140/65)
- [¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Vox Populi?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4188/65)

Comment: Las vistas pueden ser por buscadores, bots, spiders, me inclino mas por la primera: hay algo en el contenido de la pregunta o las respuestas que hace que sea un punto de entrada al sitio debido a una búsqueda. Siempre se puede mejorar la pregunta o las respuestas editándolas. Es decir si el título o el contenido es engañoso o confuso va a tener muchas vistas pero pocos votos porque no fue útil para el visitante.

Comment: @aloMalbarez recuerda que para dar un voto positivo se necesita tener una reputación de 15, puede ser que un usuario anónimo le sirvió la publicación y no pudo dar votos. Por otro lado es una gran iniciativa la que propones Rubén, hace tiempo me embarque en una campaña para traer atención a publicaciones que me parecen excelentes (a costa de mis puntos :)) tal ves se podría hacer una mezcla entre eso y una jornada de limpieza, lo importante es que los usuarios con los puntos tengan la voluntad de hacerlo.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Si a la misma busqueda en lugar de >1000 le ponemos [<1000 y anteriores a 2018](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+votes%3A0..0+views%3A..1000+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3A0+created%3A..2017) tenemos 8.5k preguntas. Si las vistas contaran bots y spiders me parece que no tendríamos preguntas tan antiguas con menos menos de 1k vistas.

Comment: @Rubén por eso me inclino mas a una entrada por buscador, pero no subestimemos la tecnología si un bot tiene acceso al api le va a pegar y traer el contenido del último tiempo ( sobre todo si es contenido efímero muy específico o de moda )

Comment: @aloMalbarez De acuerdo a [Do search engine crawling bots count toward view counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157408/289691) no los buscadores no se cuentan en las vistas.

Comment: @Rubén no nos dispersemos, hay sitios que levantan el contenido de stackexchange para mostrar publicidades, obviamente no se identifican como engine crawling bots

Comment: @aloMalbarez Me parece bien que no nos dispersemos. ¿Qué tal si publicas una pregunta sobre lo que cuenta y no cuenta como vistas de las preguntas?

Comment: @aloMalbarez seguramente no cuenten para las visitas porque en muchos casos deben obtener los datos usando la API de Stack Exchange --> https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: Esta iniciativa me parece muy interesante. Pero tengo una duda, apenas empecé a revisar algunas de las preguntas (desde la más antigua). Me consigo con [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110191/conexi%c3%b3n-remota-a-servidor-mysql-ubuntu-server), que en mi opinión no es una buena pregunta, pero está protegida. Me dije a mi mismo: *Mi mismo, esta pregunta no me gusta, porque 1: Hay imagen en vez de código, 2: No parece relacionado con programación sino con configuración de un paquete, software o librería, 3: tiene respuestas que la verdad parecen tan malas como la pregunta*...

Comment: ...a lo que voy,  ¿porqué fue protegida en vez de ser downvoted? Tal vez me estoy perdiendo algo y estoy equivocado. Es sólo una duda. Me he encontrado con casos parecidos, pero ahora que lo plantean es bueno poder aclarar la duda. Gracias.

Comment: Primero, la pregunta fue protegida `para evitar respuestas tipo "gracias!", "¡Yo también!", o spam de los nuevos usuarios`. El motivo de porque fue protegida y no "downvoted" sólo te lo puede dar quien la protegió. El tipo de protección de la pregunta referida no evita el que sea votada o editada, así que adelante, votala como te parezca que sea lo mas apropiado o bien abre una pregunta con la etiqueta [meta-tag:pregunta-específica].

Comment: Gracias, lo tomo en cuenta. Saludos